# Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datetime, timer

I need to find a bottleneck and need to accurately as possible measure time.

Is the following code snippet the best way to measure the performance?

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

// Some execution process

DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan totalTimeTaken = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

Comment: By the way, if you are not looking for something quick and dirty performance counters can be used.

Comment: If you need greater precision use Stopwatch.GetTimestamp, otherwise the answer is good.

Comment: @dbasnett Can you go into more detail in an answer?

Comment: In the above example change start and endtime to long and assign Stopwatch.GetTimestamp to them instead of DateTime.Now.  The time taken is (end-start)/Stopwatch.Frequency.

Comment: See also: [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Comment: Anytime you would use DateTime.Now, ask if you should not use DateTime.UtcNow instead. That being said, Stopwatch is the proper solution.

Comment: "Best" is subjective. This question needs to define what is meant by "best" in an objective way.

Answer (score 674, accepted):

No, it's not. Use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) (in `System.Diagnostics`)

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
PerformWork();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Stopwatch automatically checks for the existence of high-precision timers.

It is worth mentioning that `DateTime.Now` often is quite a bit slower than `DateTime.UtcNow` due to the work that has to be done with timezones, [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and such.

DateTime.UtcNow typically has a resolution of 15 ms. See [John Chapman's blog post](http://jaychapman.blogspot.com/2007/12/datetimenow-precision-issues-enter.html) about `DateTime.Now` precision for a great summary.

Interesting trivia: The stopwatch falls back on `DateTime.UtcNow` if your hardware doesn't support a high frequency counter. You can check to see if Stopwatch uses hardware to achieve high precision by looking at the static field [Stopwatch.IsHighResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx).

Comment: I'd place one PerformWork(); before Stopwatch for "heating up".

Comment: Must also add recommendation that if your `PerformWork()` is very short that you may be able to call it repeatedly and compute the average of the batch of calls. Also, time an entire batch of calls rather than starting/stopping your `Stopwatch` to avoid a strobe-effect that will muddy your timing measurements.

Comment: Stopwatch is not threadsafe on multicore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664538/is-stopwatch-elapsedticks-threadsafe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149485/best-practise-for-stopwatch-in-multi-processors-machine

Comment: sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; can also

Comment: I thought a typical Windows machine kept its hardware clock in local time and then had to look up the timezone when converting to UTC.  (A crazy system I know, but Dos 5.2 and Win3.1 were crazy beasts).

Comment: a little bit to add `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: @Pavel, to be clear, Stopwatch is recommended by Microsoft as the best solution (low overhead and high precision) on modern multicore processors that are running Windows 7 and Windows 8. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: "Windows has and will continue to invest in providing a reliable and efficient performance counter. When you need time stamps with a resolution of 1 microsecond or better and you don't need the time stamps to be synchronized to an external time reference, choose QueryPerformanceCounter.." (Stopwatch uses QPC)

Answer (score 95):

If you want something quick and dirty I would suggest using Stopwatch instead for a greater degree of precision.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// Do Work
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Alternatively, if you need something a little more sophisticated you should probably consider using a 3rd party profiler such as [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm).

Answer (score 61):

[This article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/darkness-behind-datetimenow) says that first of all you need to compare three alternatives, `Stopwatch`, `DateTime.Now` AND `DateTime.UtcNow`.

It also shows that in some cases (when performance counter doesn't exist) Stopwatch is using DateTime.UtcNow + some extra processing. Because of that it's obvious that in that case DateTime.UtcNow is the best option (because other use it + some processing)

However, as it turns out, the counter almost always exists - see *[Explanation about high-resolution performance counter and its existence related to .NET Stopwatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986701)*.

Here is a performance graph. Notice how low performance cost UtcNow has compared to alternatives:

[image]

The X axis is sample data size, and the Y axis is the relative time of the example.

One thing `Stopwatch` is better at is that it provides higher resolution time measurements. Another is its more OO nature. However, creating an OO wrapper around `UtcNow` can't be hard.

Comment: The first link appears to be broken.

Comment: became broken yep.. time machine can show it I would guess. Btw why you edit "the three" , the isn't needed here I believe.

Comment: **NOTE to future readers:** These numbers do not appear to be accurate anymore, as another test by [Tono Nam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637142) (with a little tweaking, as the original test was flawed at the time of writing) shows `Stopwatch` to be the winner, though marginally: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dSg3bN

Answer (score 19):

It's useful to push your benchmarking code into a utility class/method. The `StopWatch` class does not need to be `Disposed` or `Stopped` on error.  So, the simplest code to *time* some *action* is

```
public partial class With
{
    public static long Benchmark(Action action)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Sample calling code

```
public void Execute(Action action)
{
    var time = With.Benchmark(action);
    log.DebugFormat(“Did action in {0} ms.”, time);
}
```

Here is the extension method version

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static long Benchmark(this Action action)
    {
        return With.Benchmark(action);
    }
}
```

And sample calling code

```
public void Execute(Action action)
{
    var time = action.Benchmark()
    log.DebugFormat(“Did action in {0} ms.”, time);
}
```

Comment: What about better granularity? Many things happen in less than one ms.

Comment: Return the Elapsed property then, it's a TimeSpan. I'm just showing you the pattern. Have fun implementing it.

Comment: Return `Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` for higher precision. See this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894425/difference-between-elapsedticks-elapsedmilliseconds-elapsed-milliseconds-and-e

Answer (score 18):

The [stopwatch](http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsinc/a/timing.htm) functionality would be better (higher precision).  I'd also recommend just downloading one of the popular profilers, though ([DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm) are the ones I've used the most... the free trial for DotTrace is fully functional and doesn't nag like some of the others).

Answer (score 14):

Use the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// Do some code.

sw.Stop();

// sw.ElapsedMilliseconds = the time your "do some code" took.
```

Answer (score 11):

Ditto Stopwatch, it is way better.

Regarding performance measuring you should also check whether your "// Some Execution Process" is a very short process.

Also bear in mind that the first run of your "// Some Execution Process" might be way slower than subsequent runs.

I typically test a method by running it 1000 times or 1000000 times in a loop and I get much more accurate data than running it once.

Answer (score 9):

These are all great ways to measure time, but that is only a very indirect way to find bottleneck(s).

The most direct way to find a bottneck in a thread is to get it running, and while it is doing whatever makes you wait, halt it with a pause or break key. Do this several times. If your bottleneck takes X% of time, X% is the probability that you will catch it in the act on each snapshot.

[Here's a more complete explanation of how and why it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913#378024)

Answer (score 7):

@[Sean Chambers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/c-is-datetimenow-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-preformance#28656)

FYI, the .NET Timer class is not for diagnostics, it generates events at a preset interval, like this (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)):

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
public static void Main()
{
    // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is 
// raised.
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

So this really doesn't help you know how long something took, just that a certain amount of time has passed.

The timer is also exposed as a control in System.Windows.Forms... you can find it in your designer tool box in VS05/VS08

Answer (score 7):

This is the correct way:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // some other code

        stopWatch.Stop();

        // this not correct to get full timer resolution
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        // Correct way to get accurate high precision timing
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

For more information go through *[Use Stopwatch instead of DataTime for getting accurate performance counter](http://www.totaldotnet.com/Article/ShowArticle59_StopwatchAdvantage.aspx)*.

Answer (score 6):

*Visual Studio Team System* has some features that may help with this problem. Essentially you can write unit tests and mix them in different scenarios to run against your software as part of a stress or load test. This may help to identify areas of code that impact your applications performance the most.

Microsoft' Patterns and Practices group has some guidance in *[Visual Studio Team System Performance Testing Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/PerfTesting/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Visual%20Studio%20Team%20System%202005%20Index&referringTitle=Home)*.

Answer (score 5):

I just found a post in Vance Morrison's blog about [a CodeTimer class](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2006/10/01/779503.aspx) he wrote that makes using `StopWatch` easier and does some neat stuff on the side.

Answer (score 5):

The way I use within my programs is using the StopWatch class as shown here.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();


// Critical lines of code

long elapsedMs = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 4):

I've done very little of this sort of performance checking (I tend to just think "this is slow, make it faster") so I have pretty much always gone with this.

A google does reveal a lot of resources/articles for performance checking.

Many mention using pinvoke to get performance information. A lot of the materials I study only really mention using perfmon..

#### Edit:

Seen the talks of StopWatch.. Nice! I have learned something :)

[This looks like a good article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestWithStopwatch.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This is not professional enough:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
PerformWork();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

A more reliable version is:

```
PerformWork();

int repeat = 1000;

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
{
   PerformWork();
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / repeat);
```

In my real code, I will add GC.Collect call to change managed heap to a known state, and add Sleep call so that different intervals of code can be easily separated in ETW profile.

Answer (score -1):

Since I do not care to much about precision I ended up comparing them. I am capturing lots of packets on the network and I want to place the time when I receive each packet. Here is the code that tests 5 million iterations

```
    int iterations = 5000000;

    // Test using datetime.now
    {
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow.Second);

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if (date == DateTime.Now)
                Console.WriteLine("it is!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Done executing {iterations} iterations using datetime.now. It took {(DateTime.UtcNow - now).TotalSeconds} seconds");
    }

    // Test using datetime.utcnow
    {
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow.Second);

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if (date == DateTime.UtcNow)
                Console.WriteLine("it is!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Done executing {iterations} iterations using datetime.utcnow. It took {(DateTime.UtcNow - now).TotalSeconds} seconds");
    }

    // Test using stopwatch
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if (sw.ElapsedTicks == DateTime.Now.Ticks)
                Console.WriteLine("it is!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Done executing {iterations} iterations using stopwatch. It took {(DateTime.UtcNow - now).TotalSeconds} seconds");
    }
```

The output is:

```
Done executing 5000000 iterations using datetime.now. It took 0.8685502 seconds 
Done executing 5000000 iterations using datetime.utcnow. It took 0.1074324 seconds 
Done executing 5000000 iterations using stopwatch. It took 0.9625021 seconds
```

**So in conclusion DateTime.UtcNow is the fastest if you do not care to much about precision**. This also supports the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6986472/637142 from this question.

Comment: This is a great test. Unfortunately, in its current state it is flawed, making it seem like `Stopwatch` takes a lot more time to execute than what it actually does. In the stopwatch test you are doing an extra datetime operation (`sw.ElapsedTicks == DateTime.Now.Ticks`) which not only has to fetch the current time from the system clock, but prior to that also convert the datetime object into the current timezone since you're using `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow`. Thus you are actually testing the execution time of `DateTime.Now + Stopwatch` instead of `Stopwach` alone.

Comment: I downvoted in order to raise awareness of potential misinformation, but I will be happy to upvote instead if this is corrected. In order to make the test more correct, you should store the value of `DateTime.(Utc)Now.Ticks` prior to the loop instead, which actually makes `Stopwatch` the fastest when run on .NET 6 on my machine and on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dSg3bN