# Linq to split/analyse substrings

Tags: string, linq, split, group-by

I have got a List of strings like:

- String1
- String1.String2
- String1.String2.String3
- Other1
- Other1.Other2
- Test1
- Stuff1.Stuff1
- Text1.Text2.Text3
- Folder1.Folder2.FolderA
- Folder1.Folder2.FolderB
- Folder1.Folder2.FolderB.FolderC

Now I would like to group this into:

- String1.String2.String3
- Other1.Other2
- Test1
- Stuff1.Stuff1
- Text1.Text2.Text3
- Folder1.Folder2.FolderA
- Folder1.Folder2.FolderB.FolderC

If 
"String1" is in the next item "String1.String2" I will ignore the first one
and if the second item is in the third I will only take the third "String1.String2.String3"
and so on (n items). The string is structured like a node/path and could be split by a dot.

As you can see for the Folder example Folder2 has got two different Subfolder items so I would need both strings.

Do you know how to handle this with Linq? I would prefer VB.Net but C# is also ok.

Regards Athu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim r = input.Where(Function(e, i) i = input.Count - 1 OrElse Not input(i + 1).StartsWith(e + ".")).ToList()
```

Condition within `Where` method checks if element is last from input or is not followed by element, that contains current one.

That solution uses the fact, that input is `List(Of String)`, so `Count` and `input(i+1)` are available on `O(1)` time.

Comment: This is working well if the List(of String) is sorted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple one. Try this:

```
var lst = new List<string> { /*...*/ };

var sorted =
    from item in lst
    where lst.Last() == item || !lst[lst.IndexOf(item) + 1].Contains(item)
    select item;
```

Comment: Highly inefficient! `Last()` will enumerate whole collection every time! `IndexOf()` is linear as well.

Comment: You'll get an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

Comment: @Phil: I added `list.Last() == item` to not get an exception, works in LinqPad.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Not correct. If `source` implements `IList<T>` `Last` uses `Count` and the indexer. However, this is an implementation detail, so maybe one shouldn't rely on it...

Comment: @jaydotnet: you'll need to make an edit to your post so I can remove my down vote, although I think you should use StartsWith not Contains.

Comment: @Phil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120056/contains-is-faster-than-startswith

Comment: @jaydotnet - ok that's interesting.  However what if the list was {"String1", "String2.String1"} or {"String1", "String11.String2"}?  Actually the same question applies to my solution :(

Comment: @Phil: You are right... to solve this problem you have to define some string splitting, which is not covered by any of the given solutions.

Comment: @yaydotnet Shall I undelete my answer - I thought it ended up a bit overcomplicated?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ isn't really the correct approach here, because you need to access more than one item at a time.

I would go with something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Filter(this IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    string previous = null;
    foreach(var current in source)
    {
        if(previous != null && !current.Contains(previous))
            yield return previous;
        previous = current;
    }
    yield return previous;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = strings.Filter();
```

Answer (score 0):

the following simple line can do the trick, I'm not sure about the performance cost through

```
        List<string> someStuff = new List<string>();
        //Code to the strings here, code not added for brewity
        IEnumerable<string> result = someStuff.Where(s => someStuff.Count(x => x.StartsWith(s)) == 1);
```