# difference between Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds and (stopDateTime - startDateTime).TotalMilliseconds

Tags: c#

I have:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

DateTime start  = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(5000);

stopWatch.Stop();
DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;

//stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds approximately equals to (stop - start).TotalMilliseconds
```

So is there a difference in these measurement methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stopwatch` is more precised than the calculation of `(stop - start).TotalMilliseconds`.

Check this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923283/stopwatch-vs-using-system-datetime-now-for-timing-events).

Answer (score 4):

From msdn, [System.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx):

> The Now property is frequently used to measure performance. However,
>   because of its low resolution, it is not suitable for use as a
>   benchmarking tool. A better alternative is to use the Stopwatch class.

Answer (score 3):

Stopwatch uses/is a high performance counter which can measure one-hundredth of a millisecond if you don't query the integer ".Millisecond" property but the floating point ".Ellapsed.Totalmilliseconds" property.