# New DataContext per second

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm making a server for a game and I need to save everyone's second so I made :-

```
private static void SubmitChanges() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            using(GameDBDataContext db = new GameDBDataContext()){
                foreach(IHero hero in world.Entities.BattleEntities.OnlineHeros.Values) {
                    hero.Update(db);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Is that fine? and would it be fine if I have like 500 online heroes?

**EDIT**: Checking how long it takes :-

```
private void UpdateDatabase() {
    try {
        using(GameDBDataContext db = new GameDBDataContext()) {
            foreach(IHero hero in world.Entities.BattleEntities.OnlineHeros.Values) {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                hero.Update(db);
                DateTime after = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine((now - after).Milliseconds);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

result :-

```
-13
-10
-13
-26
-19
-24
-25
-19
-27
-22
-19
-26
-25
-21
-24
-22
```

Comment: How long does it currently take to update 1 hero?  Can't you just work it out from there?

Comment: I tested that it takes `-13
-10
-13
-26
-19
-24
-25
-19
-27
-22
-19
-26
-25
-21
-24
-22
` millisecond per one update

Comment: As an aside, you may want to look into using Stopwatch to profile your code instead of DateTime. It'll give you more precise measurements. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923283/stopwatch-vs-using-system-datetime-now-for-timing-events

Comment: How much info about hero do you want to save? And technically you don't open new dbcontext per hero. You do one update per hero.

Comment: 20ms each, 500 times, that's 10seconds.  Is it okay to do that once a second?  Ummm...  Best find a way to update all 500 in one go, or reduce the overheads for each update until you're down to about 1ms each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update this all in one sql request. Linq-to-sql has method SubmitChanges, that commit all changes in context. So you can accumulate changes on hero in loop and submit them after loop.

```
private static void SubmitChanges() 
{
    while(true) {
        try {
            using(GameDBDataContext db = new GameDBDataContext()){
                foreach(IHero hero in world.Entities.BattleEntities.OnlineHeros.Values) {
                    hero.UpdateRecord(db);
                }
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Where UpdateRecord is your Update method but exclude SubmitChanges.

Comment: technically this is not one sql request. Linq-2-sql will issue one sql statement per update. They will be wrapped in a transaction though.