# How to get the loading time of a web page in Windows Service Application using HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I'm looking for code that will help me get the loading time of a web page without Using WebBrowser() in a Windows Service Application.

I run through different methods, but I don't quite get it.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the trick:

```
Public Function WebpageResponseTime(ByVal URL As String) As TimeSpan
    Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
    sw.Start()

    Dim wRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
    Using httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(wRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            sw.Stop()
            Return sw.Elapsed
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

This will only take the downloading of the source code into account. If you want to calculate how long time it takes to download the source code AND render the page you'd have to use the `WebBrowser` class.

**How it works:**

The function declares and starts a `Stopwatch` which will be used for calculating how long the operation took, then it creates a web request to the specified URL. It downloads the entire page's source code (via the HttpWebResponse) and after that checks the response's `StatusCode`.

`StatusCode.OK` (which is HTTP status code 200) means that the request succeeded and that the requested information (the web page's source code) is in the response, but as we're not gonna use the source code for anything we let the response get disposed later by the `Using/End Using` block.

And lastly the function stops the `Stopwatch` and returns the elapsed time (how long it took to download the web page's source) to you.

**Example use:**

```
Dim PageLoadTime As TimeSpan = WebpageResponseTime("http://www.microsoft.com/")
MessageBox.Show("Response took: " & PageLoadTime.ToString())
```

Comment: You can improve on this by using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn okay, but what's the improvement of it/what's the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923283/stopwatch-vs-using-system-datetime-now-for-timing-events

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Okay. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: Bah, botched my comment edit and lost the original text :(

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Edited (not tested though, but it looks alright).

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Elphrian You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. -Oh and you should probably use the new code I wrote instead, if you aren't already.

Comment: Hey.. The system gives an error saying. The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy authentication Required.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to use HttpWebRequest. Can you please fix it for me? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Elphrian: Apparenty it means you must authenticate yourself using a proxy. My guess: you must log in to the website with a proxy. I've never known of the error before. See "**10.4.8 407 Proxy Authentication Required**": http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html