# Measure ASP.NET Website Server Side Executing Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, iis-7.5

I've a website hosted on windows hosting IIS 7.5. How can I measure server side (C#) executing time?.. Is it possible to get it without IIS?

I need some tools, software or online tools

Comment: What do you mean by "without IIS"?

Comment: do you mean diagnostic tools like this ? :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: yes, I mean some tools like fiddler but as i see fiddler can't show this

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can measure the execution time of server-side by [Stopwatch](http://code.google.com/p/nprof/) class.

> Stopwatch measures time elapsed. It is useful for micro-benchmarks in code optimization. It can perform routine and continuous performance monitoring. The Stopwatch type, found in System.Diagnostics, is useful in many contexts.

You can also find some examples of its usage [here](http://chimpswithkeyboards.com/projects/nprofiler/)

It uses a higher resolution / precision than `DateTime.Now`.

You can also check out these related links:

[Environment.TickCount vs DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243351/environment-tickcount-vs-datetime-now)

[Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)

`DateTime` is good enough for precision to the second probably but anything beyond that I would recommend `StopWatch`.

If you looking for Profilers, there are some good Open Source profilers like:

- [NProf](http://code.google.com/p/nprof/)
- [Prof-It for C#](http://dotnet.jku.at/projects/Prof-It/)
- [NProfiler](http://chimpswithkeyboards.com/projects/nprofiler/)
- [ProfileSharp](http://www.softprodigy.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be it. Profiler for MVC and WebFormas as far as I know: 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Trace directive of Page.

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08(v=vs.71).aspx