# c# stopwatch.elapsed values innaccurate

Tags: c#, .net

I want to time total runtime of a progam I am working on.

Currently the code looks similar to this (sw is a member of the program class):

```
 void Main(string[] args)
 {
     sw.Start();
     //Code here starts a thread
     //Code here joins the thread
     //Code operates on results of threaded operation
     sw.Stop();
     Console.WrtieLine("Operation took {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString());
 }
```

I assume this issue is caused by the thread taking control of the program execution but that's the operation that takes the most time and I'm supposed to avoid changing that code as other projects depend on it as well.

For reference, simple observation shows that the code takes nearly half an hour to run, but the elapsed time according to the stopwatch is only 23 seconds or so. Exact output `Operation took 00:00:23.1064841`

Comment: How inaccurate is "inaccurate"?

Comment: And there's no other code accessing `sw`?

Comment: It is unlikely that multi-threading causes such a big discrepancy. It sounds like the code in the main thread doesn't actually wait for the second thread to end before stopping the stopwatch.

Comment: correct. sw is only used in main.

Comment: What is the exact output? Are you sure it's not reporting 23 minutes?

Comment: Is the final line printed after half a hour, or after 23 sec?

Comment: @MikeDinescu The log file shows all the processing logs from the thread before the logging of the time. (The person I got the code from redirected console out to a log file.)

Comment: Test without sending output to log file

Comment: Make `sw` a local, just for the heck of it. See if anything changes.

Comment: @Chris Changing `sw` to a local didn't help.

Comment: Then I suggest abandoning `Stopwatch` and going with `Environment.TickCount` or something similar. Would be really interesting to find the cause of this though.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, `Environment.TickCount` worked well.

Comment: Still, any idea what's the problem ?

Comment: Yes,  nice alternartive,  but this doesnt explain why stopwatch behaves like this

Comment: Tick count can also be inaccurate. Here is another SO answer showing some more information that should be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8865560/2267817

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environment.TickCount vs DateTime.Now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243351/environment-tickcount-vs-datetime-now)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev not a duplicate, the accepted answer for that question is the problem that created this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the best solution is to use `Environment.TickCount` as it measures milliseconds since the system booted and is not processor-core dependent like `Stopwatch`.

```
int StartTime = Environment.TickCount;
//Your Code to measure here
int EndTime = Environment.TickCount;
int runningTime = EndTime - StartTIme; //running time in milliseconds
// code to do whatever you want with runningTime
```