# System.Threading callback does not seem that accurate

Tags: c#, timer

My application receives instructions from my client.

On each instruction I want to execute code from the received timestamp + 10 seconds.

To test the accuracy of my code I mocked up this simple console test:

```
    static DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
    static Timer _timer = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(Callback, null,200, Timeout.Infinite);
       d1 = DateTime.Now;
       Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Callback(Object state)
    {
        TimeSpan s = DateTime.Now - d1;
        Console.WriteLine("Done, took {0} secs.", s.Milliseconds);
        _timer.Change(200, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

On running it I had hoped to display:

```
Done, took 200 milsecs.
Done, took 200 milsecs.
Done, took 200 milsecs.
Done, took 200 milsecs.
Done, took 200 milsecs.
Done, took 200 milsecs.
```

But it does not.

I get random values for 'milsecs'.

NB
My actual code will not always be using 200 milliseconds.

Example Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How random of values are you getting? Do you mean it is of by 5 milliseconds or are you getting some that are off by 500 milliseconds? Please clarify.

Comment: There are many timers, which Timer class are you using? Even if you use the System.Threading.Timer though, thread switching means that there's no guarantee that will execute exactly every 200ms - that's multimedia playback accuracy.

Comment: You should be using the [StopWatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457605/how-to-measure-code-performance-in-net) class, not DateTime.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Hi, thanks. I will substitute that now and report back

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the comment, I am using the Threading Timer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right.do you know fo a technique that would give me multimedia accuracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're using the `TimeSpan.Milliseconds` property, which is an `int` and only returns the Millisecond *part* of the timespan. To make sure you're getting the full time, use [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Second, you're not resetting `d1` with each loop, so you'll see the *total* time, not the time per iteration. To fix this, make sure to set `d1 = DateTime.Now` at the end of your callback so the next loop is using the right time.

Finally, you may see a certain discrepancy rather than perfect 200ms intervals, due to the overhead of threading, method calls, and even the subtraction operation you're doing. In addition, `DateTime` does not always have the greatest accuracy - according to [this article from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx):

> If the question you want to ask is about how long some operation
>   took, and you want a high-precision, high-accuracy answer, then use
>   the [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Thus:

```
static Stopwatch _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
static Timer _timer = null;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _timer = new Timer(Callback, null,200, Timeout.Infinite);
   Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Callback(Object state)
{
    TimeSpan s = _watch.Elapsed;
    _watch.Restart();
    Console.WriteLine("Done, took {0} secs.", s.TotalMilliseconds);
    _timer.Change(200, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: "Second, you're not resetting d1 with each loop" - feel a but stupid now!

Comment: This improved my results tremendously.Thank you. I will look at the StopWatch class now. I assume I can use callbacks with this class?

Comment: Using a `Stopwatch` would replace the use of `DateTime` - I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I am now getting zero milliseconds though

Comment: That would be a mix up in `Reset` and `Restart` methods - oops!

Answer (score 1):

`s.Milliseconds` is the milliseonds after the decimal point so to speak. You need `TotalMilliseconds`. Those properties are horribly named. They are the cause for many SO questions.

The built-in timers should have about 15ms resolution (or a small multiple of it) and potentially some skew (I don't know).

Comment: I shall try that and the other suggestion above now. Thanks

Comment: Hi this WAS an issue and thanks for pointing this out.  However, the biggest problem was my poor code :(