# C# Stopwatch to calculate loop time for function

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I am not familiar with the C# stopwatch class. I am trying to find elapsed time for a function. When I call a function again I need to get the total time since the last call. How Should I do it?

I thought something like below:

```cs
public double CalculateAngle(double Theta_dot, double Psi_dot)
{
    mywatch.Stop();
    var time = mywatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
    mywatch.Start();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at teh TimeSpan class

Comment: Have a look at: [Exact time measurement for performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969290/exact-time-measurement-for-performance-testing)  and [How to measure code performance in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457605/how-to-measure-code-performance-in-net).

Comment: What is supposed to happen on first call? What's the intent of the measurement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to measure the time since the last time the method was called  then use [Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-stopwatch-restart):

> Use Restart to stop current interval measurement and start a new interval measurement.

```
public double CalculateAngle(double Theta_dot, double Psi_dot)
{
   TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
   mywatch.Restart();
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you'd put restart at the start or end of the method...

Answer (score 1):

You can store execution times in a global list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static List<long> executionTimes = new List<long>();
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            watch.Start();
            MyFunction();
            var elapsed = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            executionTimes.Add(elapsed);
        }
    
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("; ", executionTimes));
    }
    public static async Task MyFunction()
    {
        //your function...
    }
}
```

If you need, you can use Stop() or Restart() methods of watch.