# Determine page load times in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know there are a lot of tools out there on the client that let you know how long a page takes to load but what could I do on the server to see how long it takes an ASP.net MVC page to render? I don't need to know how long it took all of the images to load and the javascript to start running, I'd just like to know how long all of the server-side logic took to run and potentially log that info to a db...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712276/page-render-time-in-mvc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page generation time - ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826657/page-generation-time-asp-net-mvc) - c'mon man, almost all the suggested questions for your question title answer your question  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add code to global.asax for OnBeginRequest and OnEndRequest, or create a custom HttpModeule or HttpHandler.