# LINQ extension methods - Any() vs. Where() vs. Exists()

Tags: c#, linq

Unfortunately the names of these methods make terrible search terms, and I've been unable to find a good resource that explains the difference between these methods--as in when to use each.

Thanks.

Edit:

The sort of query that I'm trying to fully understand is something like this:

```
context.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == bookID)).ToList();
```

And thanks to all who've answered.

Comment: I would also recommend [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`Where` returns a new sequence of items matching the predicate.

`Any` returns a Boolean value; there's a version with a predicate (in which case it returns whether or not any items match) and a version without (in which case it returns whether the query-so-far contains any items).

I'm not sure about `Exists` - it's not a LINQ standard query operator. If there's a version for the Entity Framework, perhaps it checks for existence based on a key - a sort of specialized form of `Any`? (There's an `Exists` method in `List<T>` which is similar to `Any(predicate)` but that predates LINQ.)

Comment: @JonH: Yes, as I posted, it's part of `List<T>` - not part of LINQ.

Comment: But in function, `.Any` and `.Exists` are exactly the same.

Comment: @Flater: Which version of `Exists`? `List<T>.Exists`?

Answer (score 8):

> > context.Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == bookID)).ToList();

`a.Books` is the list of books by that author.  The property is automatically created by Linq-to-Sql, provided you have a foreign-key relationship set up.

So, `a.Books.Any(b => b.BookID == bookID)` translates to "Do any of the books by this author have an ID of bookID", which makes the complete expression "Who are the authors of the book with id bookID?"

That could also be written something like

```
  from a in context.Authors
  join b in context.Books on a.AuthorId equal b.AuthorID
  where b.BookID == bookID
  select a;
```

UPDATE:
  `Any()` as far as I know, only returns a `bool`.  Its effective implementation is:

```
 public Any(this IEnumerable<T> coll, Func<T, bool> predicate)
 {
     foreach(T t in coll)
     {
         if (predicte(t))
            return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: I think the part that is throwing me is how Any() returns a bool, which means I'm reading "yes, the author does have a book in their collection that has this BookID."  Is their another overload of Any() that returns something different?

Comment: Yeah, this is why I'm confused.  The way the Any() method is chained makes no sense to me.  It doesn't return a book, but rather a bool.  Man alive am I out to sea on this one.  Maybe I just need another pot of coffee.  Thanks for all the effort, btw.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. Any() returns a bool, Where() expects a bool. Everyone's happy!

Comment: This dunce cap makes my head itch, and gets distracting sometimes.  I'm sure I'll get it eventually.

Comment: As far as I understand the difference between Any() and Where(), is that Any returns true if the conditions are met where Where returns the elements that meet the condition.

So use Any to ask if any books have the particular ID and use Where to ask which books have the the ID (and have them returned)

Answer (score 7):

Just so you can find it next time, here is how you search for the enumerable Linq extensions. The methods are static methods of Enumerable, thus Enumerable.Any, Enumerable.Where and Enumerable.Exists.

- [google.com/search?q=Enumerable.Any](http://www.google.com/search?q=Enumerable.Any)
- [google.com/search?q=Enumerable.Where](http://www.google.com/search?q=Enumerable.Where)
- <strike>[google.com/search?q=Enumerable.Exists](http://www.google.com/search?q=Enumerable.Exists)</strike>

As the third returns no usable result, I found that you meant List.Exists, thus:

- [google.com/search?q=List.Exists](http://www.google.com/search?q=List.Exists)

I also recommend [hookedonlinq.com](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/) as this is has very comprehensive and clear guides, as well clear explanations of the behavior of Linq methods in relation to deferness and lazyness.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I searched for  "ienumerable<>.any()" , which was close, I guess, but useless.

Answer (score 3):

Any - boolean function that returns true when any of object in list satisfies condition set in function parameters. For example:

```
List<string> strings = LoadList();
boolean hasNonEmptyObject = strings.Any(s=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Where - function that returns list with all objects in list that satisfy condition set in function parameters. For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> nonEmptyStrings = strings.Where(s=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Exists - basically the same as any but it's not generic - it's defined in List class, while Any is defined on IEnumerable interface.

Comment: Your second example won't compile, as Where returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

`Any()` returns true if any of the elements in a collection meet your predicate's criteria. (`Any()` does not iterate through the entire collection, as it returns upon the first match.)

`Where()` returns an enumerable of **all** elements in a collection that meet your predicate's criteria.

`Exists()` does the same thing as `Any()` except it's just an older implementation that was there on the `List` back before LINQ.

Comment: Not on IList - only `List<T>`

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable introduces quite a number of extensions to it which helps you to pass your own delegate and invoking the resultant from the IEnumerable back. Most of them are by nature of type Func

The Func takes an argument T and returns TResult.

In case of

Where - Func  : So it takes IEnumerable of T and Returns a bool. The where will ultimately returns the IEnumerable of T's for which Func returns true.

So if you have 1,5,3,6,7 as IEnumerable and you write .where(r => r<5) it will return a new IEnumerable of 1,3.

Any - Func basically is similar in signature but returns true only when any of the criteria returns true for the IEnumerable. In our case, it will return true as there are few elements present with r<5.

Exists  - Predicate on the other hand will return true only when any one of the predicate returns true. 
So in our case if you pass .Exists(r => 5) will return true as 5 is an element present in IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in model.Where(x => !model2.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID)).ToList())
{
enter code here
}
```

same work you also can do with `Contains`

secondly `Where` is give you new list of values.
thirdly using `Exist` is not a good practice, you can achieve your target from `Any` and `contains` like

```
EmployeeDetail _E = Db.EmployeeDetails.where(x=>x.Id==1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this will clear your confusion.