# Performance difference between .where(...).Any() vs ..Any(...)

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ extension methods - Any() vs. Where() vs. Exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703256/linq-extension-methods-any-vs-where-vs-exists)

Given a list of objects in memory I ran the following two expressions:

```
myList.where(x => x.Name == "bla").Any()
```

vs

```
myList.Any(x => x.Name == "bla")
```

The latter was fastest always, I believe this is due to the Where enumerating all items. But this also happens when there's no matches.

Im not sure of the exact WHY though. Are there any cases where this viewed performance difference wouldn't be the case, like if it was querying Nhib?

Cheers.

Comment: What tests have you run? How many iterations? What kind of differences in performance are we talking here?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10110013/284240

Comment: Quick correction: I suspect you meant `==` rather than `=`.

Comment: Voting to close. The answers to this question provide ample insight - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703256/linq-extension-methods-any-vs-where-vs-exists

Comment: SearchQueryDTO is a class with string property called Name.                 IList<SearchQueryDTO> myList = new List<SearchQueryDTO>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                myList.Add(new SearchQueryDTO { Name = i.ToString()});
            }
            var timer2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var res2 = myList.Any(x => x.Name == "499");
            var time2 = timer2.Elapsed; //around .5 ms
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var res = myList.Where(x => x.Name == "499").Any();
            var time1 = timer.Elapsed; //around 3.5 ms

Comment: @JonSkeet he must have meant `==` as `=` would result in a compile error "cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'".

Comment: @marky: I'd edit your post, don't put code in a comment unless it is **very** small snippet...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'd say it shouldn't make any *major* difference, the implementation of `Any()` with predicate and `Where()` with `Any()` have very different effects.  The former simply iterates through a normal foreach loop, the latter pulls an iterator thorugh a foreach loop, which is just *slightly* less efficient.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: Indeed. I just didn't want to correct it silently...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: Yes, i've got the point. But it's more important to emphasize that `Where` _does **not** need to enumerate all items_ as mentioned. That's a common mistake.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: absolutely agree on that point, just wasn't sure if you were saying he shouldn't be seeing a difference at all, sorry!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, voting to re-open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Any()` with the predicate can perform its task without an iterator (`yield return`).  Using a `Where()` creates an iterator, which adds has a performance impact (albeit very small).

Thus, performance-wise (by a bit), you're better off using the form of `Any()` that takes the predicate (`x => x.Name == "bla"`).  Which, personally, I find more readable as well...

On a side note, `Where()` does not necessarily enumerate over all elements, it just creates an iterator that will travel over the elements as they are requested, thus the call to `Any()` after the `Where()` will drive the iteration, which will stop at the first item it finds that matches the condition.

So the performance difference is **not** that `Where()` iterates over **all** the items (in linq-to-objects) because it really doesn't need to (unless, of course, it doesn't find one that satisfies it), it's that the `Where()` clause has to set up an iterator to walk over the elements, whereas `Any()` with a predicate does not.

Comment: James, thanks for clearing this up for me this! I ran it a few times and was always getting this performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you correct `where` to `Where` and `=` to `==`, I'd expect the "`Any` with a predicate" version to execute *very slightly faster*. However, I would expect the situations in which the difference was significant to be few and far between, so you should aim for readability first.

As it happens, I would normally prefer the "`Any` with a predicate" version in terms of readability too, so you win on both fronts - but you should really go with what you find more readable first. *Measure* the performance in scenarios you actually care about, and if a section of code isn't performing as you need it to, *then* consider micro-optimizing it - measuring at every step, of course.

Comment: +1 for Any with a predicate, and focus on readability

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this is due to the Where enumerating all items.

If `myList` is a collection in memory, it doesn't. The `Where` method uses deferred execution, so it will only enumerate as many items as needed to determine the result. In that case you would not see any significant difference between `.Any(...)` and `.Where(...).Any()`.

> Are there any cases where this viewed performance difference wouldn't
>   be the case, like if it was querying Nhib?

Yes, if `myList` is a data source that will take the expression generated by the methods and translate to a query to run elsewhere (e.g. LINQ To SQL), you may see a difference. The code that translates the expression simply does a better job at translating one of the expressions.