# Is there a "correct" way between these two statements that filter and return a boolean using LINQ to Objects?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to determine if there is a correct way to first filter a collection and then determine if any items in the collections pass the filter condition.  The two (basic) statements I'm trying to compare are listed below.

I've tried doing some research on the topic, but haven't found much concrete information on this particular situation. I know the order of LINQ statements matter in how they are compiled and executed ([Does the order of LINQ functions matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499384/does-the-order-of-linq-functions-matter)), but I wasn't sure if calling `.Where(x => x.Prop1 == 0).Any()` would be opposed to calling just `.Any(x => x.Prop1 == 0)` or if either method doesn't really make a difference since the end result would be the same.

Let's say there is a class called SomeObject.

```
    class SomeObject
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The two statements I'm trying to compare are:

Method #1

```
var test1 = new List<SomeObject>();
bool condition1 = test1.Where(x => x.Prop1 == 0).Any();
```

Method #2

```
var test2 = new List<SomeObject>();
bool condition2 = test2.Any(x => x.Prop1 == 0);
```

Based on my understanding of LINQ to Objects method #2 would be preferred because it will "short-circuit" using just the single `.Any(x => x.Prop1 == 0)` method call. Where as I think method #1 would iterate through every item with the filter applied in `.Where(x => x.Prop1 == 0)` and **then** determine if there are any items in the filtered collection with `.Any()`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800560/performance-difference-between-where-any-vs-any which has itself been marked a duplicate? Have you seen these resources?

Comment: @CaiusJard I had not until just now and they answer my question very clearly.  Apparently I need to improving my searching skills! Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write a question out to see what the question is ;) and sometimes when youv'e thought about a question for so long that you can't see how to think about it in simple terms any more then it's a good time for a second pair of eyes! - I googled for "linq where any vs any" and hit that link as the second result. Looks like Servy might have done the same (and he has a lot of closevote power in .net questions)