# Performance Benchmarking of Contains, Exists and Any

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking

I have been searching for a performance benchmarking between `Contains`, `Exists` and `Any` methods available in the `List<T>`. I wanted to find this out just out of curiosity as I was always confused among these. Many questions on SO described definitions of these methods such as:

1. [LINQ Ring: Any() vs Contains() for Huge Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections)
2. [Linq .Any VS .Exists - Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference?rq=1)
3. [LINQ extension methods - Any() vs. Where() vs. Exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703256/linq-extension-methods-any-vs-where-vs-exists?lq=1)

So I decided to do it myself. I am adding it as an answer. Any more insight on the results is most welcomed. I also did this benchmarking for arrays to see the results

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**According to documentation:**

List.Exists (Object method)

> Determines whether the List(T) contains elements that match the
> conditions defined by the specified predicate.

IEnumerable.Any (Extension method)

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

List.Contains (Object Method)

> Determines whether an element is in the List.

**Benchmarking:**

***CODE:***

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainsExistsAnyShort();

        ContainsExistsAny();
    }
    
    private static void ContainsExistsAny()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("********* ContainsExistsAny ***********");
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************");

        List<int> list = new List<int>(6000000);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(random.Next(6000000));
        }
        int[] arr = list.ToArray();

        find(list, arr);
    }

    private static void ContainsExistsAnyShort()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("***** ContainsExistsAnyShortRange *****");
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************");

        List<int> list = new List<int>(2000);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(random.Next(6000000));
        }
        int[] arr = list.ToArray();

        find(list, arr);
    }

    private static void find(List<int> list, int[] arr)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] find = new int[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            find[i] = random.Next(6000000);
        }

        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
        {
            list.Contains(find[rpt]);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List/Contains: {0:N0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
        {
            list.Exists(a => a == find[rpt]);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List/Exists: {0:N0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
        {
            list.Any(a => a == find[rpt]);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List/Any: {0:N0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
        {
            arr.Contains(find[rpt]);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Array/Contains: {0:N0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Arrays do not have Exists");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
        {
            arr.Any(a => a == find[rpt]);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Array/Any: {0:N0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

**RESULTS**

```
***************************************
***** ContainsExistsAnyShortRange *****
***************************************
List/Contains: 96ms
List/Exists: 146ms
List/Any: 381ms
Array/Contains: 34ms
Arrays do not have Exists
Array/Any: 410ms
***************************************
********* ContainsExistsAny ***********
***************************************
List/Contains: 257,996ms
List/Exists: 379,951ms
List/Any: 884,853ms
Array/Contains: 72,486ms
Arrays do not have Exists
Array/Any: 1,013,303ms
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that though Contains seem to be the fastest, LINQ 2 SQL has a limitation of ~2100 objects in the list, so it would be good for shorter lists.

Comment: @jyparask Even for the larger lists Contains seems good. However, I have updated the code and timings for the shorter list too. The result is as you predicted.

Comment: I ran your benchmark and I obtained that List.Exists was actually slightly faster than List.Contains, 45ms vs 55ms. The rest seemed consistent with your results. Tested on .NET 4.5 using Visual Studio 2013 in 32-bit in Release mode with optimizations.

Comment: What do you mean: "Arrays do not have Exists"? I think it has Exists(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22928748/4608491

Comment: "Arrays do not have Exists" ? `Array.Exists(` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It would have been interesting to compare these performances with traditional loop search (`for` or `foreach`).

Answer (score 106):

The fastest way is to use a `HashSet`.
The `Contains` for a `HashSet` is O(1).

I took your code and added a benchmark for `HashSet<int>`
The performance cost of `HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(list);` is nearly zero.

### Code

```
void Main()
{
    ContainsExistsAnyVeryShort();
    
    ContainsExistsAnyShort();

    ContainsExistsAny();
}

private static void ContainsExistsAny()
{
    Console.WriteLine("***************************************");
    Console.WriteLine("********* ContainsExistsAny ***********");
    Console.WriteLine("***************************************");

    List<int> list = new List<int>(6000000);
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6000000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(random.Next(6000000));
    }
    int[] arr = list.ToArray();
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(list);

    find(list, arr, set, (method, stopwatch) => $"{method}: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

}

private static void ContainsExistsAnyShort()
{
    Console.WriteLine("***************************************");
    Console.WriteLine("***** ContainsExistsAnyShortRange *****");
    Console.WriteLine("***************************************");

    List<int> list = new List<int>(2000);
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        list.Add(random.Next(6000000));
    }
    int[] arr = list.ToArray();
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(list);

    find(list, arr, set, (method, stopwatch) => $"{method}: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

}

private static void ContainsExistsAnyVeryShort()
{
    Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
    Console.WriteLine("***** ContainsExistsAnyVeryShortRange *****");
    Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");

    List<int> list = new List<int>(10);
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.Add(random.Next(6000000));
    }
    int[] arr = list.ToArray();
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(list);

    find(list, arr, set, (method, stopwatch) => $"{method}: {stopwatch.ElapsedTicks} ticks");

}

private static void find(List<int> list, int[] arr, HashSet<int> set, Func<string, Stopwatch, string> format)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] find = new int[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        find[i] = random.Next(6000000);
    }

    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        list.Contains(find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("List/Contains", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        list.Exists(a => a == find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("List/Exists", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        list.Any(a => a == find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("List/Any", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        arr.Contains(find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("Array/Contains", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        Array.Exists(arr, a => a == find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("Array/Exists", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        Array.IndexOf(arr, find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("Array/IndexOf", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        arr.Any(a => a == find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("Array/Any", watch));

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 10000; rpt++)
    {
        set.Contains(find[rpt]);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(format("HashSet/Contains", watch));
}
```

#### RESULTS

```
*******************************************
***** ContainsExistsAnyVeryShortRange *****
*******************************************
List/Contains: 1067 ticks
List/Exists: 2884 ticks
List/Any: 10520 ticks
Array/Contains: 1880 ticks
Array/Exists: 5526 ticks
Array/IndexOf: 601 ticks
Array/Any: 13295 ticks
HashSet/Contains: 6629 ticks
***************************************
***** ContainsExistsAnyShortRange *****
***************************************
List/Contains: 4ms
List/Exists: 28ms
List/Any: 138ms
Array/Contains: 6ms
Array/Exists: 34ms
Array/IndexOf: 3ms
Array/Any: 96ms
HashSet/Contains: 0ms
***************************************
********* ContainsExistsAny ***********
***************************************
List/Contains: 11504ms
List/Exists: 57084ms
List/Any: 257659ms
Array/Contains: 11643ms
Array/Exists: 52477ms
Array/IndexOf: 11741ms
Array/Any: 194184ms
HashSet/Contains: 3ms
```

#### Edit (2021-08-25)

I added a comparison for very short collections (10 items) and also added `Array.Contains` and `Array.IndexOf`. You can see that `Array.IndexOf` is the fastest for such small ranges. That is, because as @lucky-brian said n is so small here, that a `for`-loop performs better than a somewhat complex search algorithm. However I still advice to use `HashSet<T>` whenever possible, as it better reflects the intend of only having unique values and the difference for small collections is below 1ms.

Comment: I was looking for exactly such a thing. I was like "Holy Molly" when I saw the performance on the HashSet/Contains. Definitely going to try that out in my environment of 1000 .. 5000 items.

Comment: Would have been nice to see the performance of a HashMap as well here.

Comment: Do you know if the Any for a HashSet is aslo O(1)?

Comment: Any does not exist on `HashSet<T>` but is an extension Method for `IEnumerable<T>` and is O(1) without a predicate and O(n) with a predicate. Herse is the source: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1288

Comment: "Arrays do not have Exists" ? `Array.Exists(` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Just a quick point, having order O(1) doesn't necessarily mean that an algorithm is fast, it just means that its speed doesn't depend on the number of elements over which it is applied. It might still take a very long time to complete.

Answer (score 5):

It is worth mentioning that this comparison is a bit unfair, since the `Array` class doesn't own the `Contains()` method. It uses an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` via a sequential `Enumerator`, hence it is not optimized for `Array` instances. On the other side, `HashSet<T>` has its own implementation fully optimized for all sizes.

To compare fairly you could use the static method `int Array.IndexOf()` which is implemented for `Array` instances, even though it uses a `for` loop slightly more efficient that an `Enumerator`.

Using a fair comparison algorithm, the performance for small sets of up to 5 elements of `HashSet<T>.Contains()` is similar to the `Array.IndexOf()` but it is much more efficient for larger sets.