# LINQ groupby search in contains

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following result:

```
var result = (from p1 in db.Table
              select new ReportInform 
              {
                  DataValue =  p1.DataValue, 
                  SampleDate = p1.SampleDate 
              })
              .Distinct()
              .ToList();

// Next getting list of duplicate SampleDates
var duplicates = result.GroupBy(x => x.SampleDate)
                       .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                       .Select (x => x)
                       .ToList();


foreach (var r in result)
{
    if (duplicates.Contains(r.SampleDate)) // get error here on incompatbility 
    {
        r.SampleDate = r.SampleDate.Value.AddMilliseconds(index++);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve? BTW `.Select (x => x)` is redundant

Comment: Stop masking the type you dont know with `var` and you will see your issues...

Comment: @GiladGreen For entries that are duplicates, I like to add millseconds to it so at the end there are no duplicates in the result set.

Comment: I think you mean `.Select (x => x.Key)` instead of `.Select (x => x)` ?

Comment: If you do `.Distinct()` you shouldn't have duplicates (if you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Comment: `For entries that are duplicates, I like to add millseconds to it so at the end there are no duplicates in the result set.` <= that is not fail proof. What if there is a non duplicate that has that same value as a duplicate (ie. duplicate's value + 1 millisecond). What are you really trying to do? Why do you care if there are duplicate datetime values?

Comment: @GiladGreen even better, if result was actually HashSet<T>, it removes the needs for Distinct and ToList, making everything faster because it does it behind the scene and no need to make a concrete list on top of the enumeration

Comment: Use Any() instead of Contains:duplicates.Any(x => x.Key == r.SampleDate).

Comment: @jdweng Actually, for list, any is slower than contains - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651940/performance-benchmarking-of-contains-exists-and-any

Comment: Is contains() only looking at the key or the entire object?

Comment: @giladgreen `Distinct` applies to all properties so it is possible to have duplicated dates since they may have different `DataPoint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting `duplicates` to be of type `List<DateTime?>` then you meant to write this

```
.Select(x => x.Key)
```

instead of

```
.Select(x => x)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.Linq.IGrouping

That error is pretty clear but may not be at a first glance. As a programmer, you need to learn how to read, understand and make sense of compiler or runtime errors.

Anyhow it is complaining that it cannot convert `DateTime?` to `System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime, ReportInForm>`. Why? Because this query returns an `System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime, ReportInForm>`

```
var duplicates = result.GroupBy(x => x.SampleDate)
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                   .Select (x => x)
                   .ToList();
```

The `GroupBy` method returns `IGrouping<System.DateTime, ReportInForm>` which has a `Key` and the `Key` is the thing you grouped by and a list of items in that group. You are grouping by `SampleDate` and checking if there are more than one items in that group and then selecting the group. Thus `dulplicates` has a list of `IGrouping<System.DateTime, ReportInForm>` and you are asking the runtime to check if it contains a `DateTime?` and it blows up at this line:

```
duplicates.Contains(r.SampleDate)
```

One way to fix this is: What you want to do is to select the key of that group. Thus do this:

```
.Select (x => x.Key)
```

Comment: @Igor, your answer wasn't bad, but this answer makes it clearer the reasons behind why the OP had troubles and why this is the way to go. +1