# Flood fill algorithm is causing OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, out-of-memory, flood-fill

Well, I'm getting the outline (path) of a building. And there is a problem. When I iterate it's pixels I check if the current pixel is white to start detecting it's walls.

[image: ...]

[image: ...]

What happens with this? When the detection is finished it starts again and again, because the next iterated pixel is also white. That's why I need to use a flood fill algorithm (to flag that the current build is completed).

Well, I have already implemented it, but I have problems.

```
    public static void FloodFill(ref Color[] source, Point pt, int width, int height, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor)
    {
        Stack<Point> pixels = new Stack<Point>();

        targetColor = source[P(pt.x, pt.y, width, height)];
        pixels.Push(pt);

        while (pixels.Count > 0)
        {
            Point a = pixels.Pop();

            if (source[P(a.x, a.y, width, height)] == targetColor)
            {
                source[P(a.x, a.y, width, height)] = replacementColor;

                if (a.x > 0)
                    pixels.Push(new Point(a.x - 1, a.y));

                if (a.x < width)
                    pixels.Push(new Point(a.x + 1, a.y));

                if (a.y > 0)
                    pixels.Push(new Point(a.x, a.y - 1));

                if (a.y < height)
                    pixels.Push(new Point(a.x, a.y + 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Extracted from: https://simpledevcode.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/flood-fill-algorithm-using-c-net/

The problem here is that by some reason, ref keyword isn't taking effect.

My implementation:

```
    private IEnumerator MainGenerationDebug(Color[] source, Color32[] target, int width, int height)
    {
        // (1)
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; Interlocked.Increment(ref i))
        {
            // (2)
            Color c = source[i];

            // (3)
            int x = i % width,
                y = i / width;

            // (4) & (5)
            yield return IntMapIteration(source, target, width, c, i, exceptions, (s, t) =>
            {
                source = s;
                target = t;
            });

            // (6)
            if (c == Color.white)
            {
                F.FloodFill(ref source, new Point(x, y), width, height, Color.white, Color.red);
            }
        }
    }
```

The process is the following:

1. I start looping all pixels, because I'm in another thread I use Interlocked.Increment.
2. I get the current color
3. I get the current x, y (2D) from the index (1D)
4. Due to I'm in a Coroutine (I'm debugging so I need to see what's happening) I use yielding
5. When the IEnumerator finishes I call an Action. (I use IEnumerators because I'm calling an Coroutine in Unity3D)
6. After everything finishes, if the current pixel is white, I start flood-filling the array.

I think everything is correct. By maybe I'm missing something.

What could you say about this?

Comment: Among other issues with this code: inside `FloodFill` the parameter `targetColor` is overwritten with the color of the start point. Maybe you want to exit `FloodFill` immediately, if this point was already set to `replacementColor`?

Comment: "The problem here is that by some reason, ref keyword isn't taking effect." - I've no idea why you're using `ref` or what you mean by "isn't taking effect". `ref` is only relevant if you *assign* to `source` (the variable itself), which you don't appear to do.

Comment: You may want to compare with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290317/how-can-i-fill-part-of-image-with-color/45299760#45299760) working example.. - Also note that this `if (c == Color.white)` is, typo aside, __not recommended__. Better use To/FromArgb as the predefined Colors never match simple colors

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm setting source inside FloodFill.

Comment: @Henrik I didn't fully understand you, can you explain more in detail, please.

Comment: @TaW I'm using a custom Color struct written by me.

Comment: So you have overridden Drawing.Color?? Very confusing to use the same name, imo..

Comment: @TaW That's because I'm on Unity.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And you ought to have tagged it as such !!!

Comment: No, nowhere in `FloodFill` do you do `source = <something>;`.

Comment: @z3nth10n - you're setting a value "inside" the array (`array[index] = value`). You don't need `ref` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an own implementation to show what's happening and why it's better to use HashSet.

Why used HashSet? [HashSet.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_Contains__0_) [is quicklier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920719/3286975)).

This is the actual implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class F
{
    /// <summary>
           /// Floods the fill.
           /// </summary>
           /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
           /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
           /// <param name="x">The x.</param>
           /// <param name="y">The y.</param>
           /// <param name="width">The width.</param>
           /// <param name="height">The height.</param>
           /// <param name="target">The target to replace.</param>
           /// <param name="replacement">The replacement.</param>
    public static void FloodFill<T>(this T[] source, int x, int y, int width, int height, T target, T replacement)
    {
        int i = 0;

        FloodFill(source, x, y, width, height, target, replacement, out i);
    }

    /// <summary>
           /// Floods the array following Flood Fill algorithm
           /// </summary>
           /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
           /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
           /// <param name="x">The x.</param>
           /// <param name="y">The y.</param>
           /// <param name="width">The width.</param>
           /// <param name="height">The height.</param>
           /// <param name="target">The target to replace.</param>
           /// <param name="replacement">The replacement.</param>
           /// <param name="i">The iterations made (if you want to debug).</param>
    public static void FloodFill<T>(this T[] source, int x, int y, int width, int height, T target, T replacement, out int i)
    {
        i = 0;

        // Queue of pixels to process. :silbar:
        HashSet<int> queue = new HashSet<int>();

        queue.Add(Pn(x, y, width));

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            int _i = queue.First(),
              _x = _i % width,
              _y = _i / width;

            queue.Remove(_i);

            if (source[_i].Equals(target))
                source[_i] = replacement;

            for (int offsetX = -1; offsetX < 2; offsetX++)
                for (int offsetY = -1; offsetY < 2; offsetY++)
                {
                    // do not check origin or diagonal neighbours
                    if (offsetX == 0 && offsetY == 0 || offsetX == offsetY || offsetX == -offsetY || -offsetX == offsetY)
                        continue;

                    int targetIndex = Pn(_x + offsetX, _y + offsetY, width);
                    int _tx = targetIndex % width,
                      _ty = targetIndex / width;

                    // skip out of bounds point
                    if (_tx < 0 || _ty < 0 || _tx >= width || _ty >= height)
                        continue;

                    if (!queue.Contains(targetIndex) && source[targetIndex].Equals(target))
                    {
                        queue.Add(targetIndex);
                        ++i;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    public static int Pn(int x, int y, int w)
    {
        return x + (y * w);
    }
}
```

You can see it here working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZacRiB (using Stack was O(4n) (I figured out how to solve this problem, but I dont find the actual code) and HashSet is O(n - 1)).