# How do I know the current value is already stored in the database ? [with LINQ and best performance]

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, unique-constraint

I have **UserName Column** in my table and its is unique

I want have Linq Method that check current UserName is duplicate or not ?
check UserName column in database and return boolean result

BUT I need a linq method with best performance (maybe using **IQueryable**)

Can anyone help me and suggest **IsDuplicate method** with *Linq* with *best performance* ???

thanks

Comment: What have you tried and benchmarked?  Has this shown to be a noticeable bottle-neck in your code?  Is it obviously too slow now?  Why are you worrying about this?

Comment: Did you try `System.Linq Any()`? [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I must check UserName in validation layer of my application so I need an IsDuplicate Linq Method for checking before any insert with best performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the context of the database and store it in the `db` variable. After that you can call the method `IsDuplicate` which will check if there is *any* user with given username:

```
private DbContext db;

public bool IsDuplicate(string userName)
{
    return db.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == userName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for it. Select (on SQL level). THe rest is a detail any programmer worth a cent can optimize, so I do not go into it (hint: optimal performance means correct indices).

YOu can do an ANY on the LINQ level, or you can ask for the object - the later may be smarter becaue "true/false" often is a bad UI and you may want to have some more information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703256/linq-extension-methods-any-vs-where-vs-exists) thread

It's a any vs where discussion

> `Here` is the content in case it gets deleted.
>
> Where returns a new sequence of items matching the predicate.
>
> `Any` returns a Boolean value; there's a version with a predicate (in
>   which case it returns whether or not any items match) and a version
>   without (in which case it returns whether the query-so-far contains
>   any items).
>
> I'm not sure about Exists - it's not a LINQ standard query operator.
>   If there's a version for the Entity Framework, perhaps it checks for
>   existence based on a key - a sort of specialized form of Any? (There's
>   an Exists method in List which is similar to Any(predicate) but
>   that predates LINQ.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I quoted the text and added it to the post