# How to detect that one field of collection exist into another list with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I try to detect that `AirCoNam1` field exist into `airlines` list or no. I wrote this linq query but get error.

`aFlightList` is a collection that contain `AirCoNam1` field.

How to fix this?

```
  aFlightList=aFlightList.Any(  airlines.Contains(x=>x.AirCoNam1)).ToArray();
```

Comment: what you need is `Where` not `Any`....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703256/linq-extension-methods-any-vs-where-vs-exists

Comment: what exactly is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is this :

```
  aFlightList=aFlightList.Where(x=>airlines.Contains(x.AirCoNam1)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Intersect` Linq method

```
var doesContain = aFlightList.Intersect(airlines.Select(a => a.AirCoNam1)).Any();
```

Comment: @programmer138200 in what way?

Comment: @programmer138200 It's impossible to help anyone who doesn't let people help him, "it doesn't work" isn't helpful, what doesn't work, what error are you getting, what output are you getting and what output do you expect. Just saying it doesn't work is no help at all

Answer (score 0):

`Any()` returns boolean. You can't call `ToList()` on a boolean value. It isn't clear from the question, but looks like you want to use `Any()` in a where clause, something like the following :

```
aFlightList = aFlightList.Where(f => airlines.Any(a => a == f.AirCoNam1))
                         .ToArray();
```