# LINQ equivalent of List<T>.Find()?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking at some code that takes an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and converts it to a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) so it can use [`List<T>.Find(predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx):

```
var myEnumerable = ...;
var myList = new List<T>(myEnumerable);
var match = myList.Find(value => value.Aaa == aaa && value.Bbb == bbb);
```

Is there a way to rewrite this using the [LINQ extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) that has the same effect, but without building an extra `List<T>` as an intermediate step?

The [`FirstOrDefault(source, predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) extension method looks like a good candidate, but trying to figure out if it's *exactly* equivalent to `Find` is making my head hurt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LINQ equivelent would be to use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx):

```
var match = myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(value => value.Aaa == aaa && value.Bbb == bbb);
```

Comment: That's what I suspected, but it's good to hear confirmation from someone with more rep than me (grin). So this does deal with all the edge cases the same way? (Empty collection, nothing that matches, any other exceptional conditions)

Comment: @Joe: Yes.  It's going to give you the same results - the first match, or `default(T)` in the case of no matching elements.  It's effectively identical, except that it works on any `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 25):

Just for reference, here is a table of some old .NET 2 style `List<>` instance methods, and their equivalent extension methods in Linq:

```
METHOD IN List<>                              METHOD IN Linq
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

list.Contains(item)                           query.Contains(item)

list.Exists(x => x.IsInteresting())           query.Any(x => x.IsInteresting())
list.TrueForAll(x => x.IsInteresting())       query.All(x => x.IsInteresting())

list.Find(x => x.IsInteresting())             query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsInteresting())
list.FindLast(x => x.IsInteresting())         query.LastOrDefault(x => x.IsInteresting())

list.FindAll(x => x.IsInteresting())          query.Where(x => x.IsInteresting())

list.ConvertAll(x => x.ProjectToSomething())  query.Select(x => x.ProjectToSomething())
```

Of course some of them are not entirely equivalent. In particular Linq's `Where` and `Select` use deferred execution, while `FindAll` and `ConvertAll` of `List<>` will execute immediately and return a reference to a new `List<>` instance.

`FindLast` will often be faster than `LastOrDefault` because `FindLast` actually searches starting from the end of the `List<>`. On the other hand `LastOrDefault(predicate)` always runs through the entire sequence (starting from the first item), and only then returns the most "recent" match.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do the following way:

```
var match = myEnumerable.Where(value => value.Aaa == aaa && value.Bbb == bbb)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is querying twice, which is not needed because you can achieve the desired result only with FirstOrDefault

Comment: @danderson: Not true - LINQ uses deferred execution, so the "query" will stop executing as soon as the first element is found.  This really isn't much less efficient than just using FirstOrDefault directly [very slightly less efficient, but only microscopically so].  There is still only at most one iteration through the sequence...

Comment: I ran some performance tests and verified this, but do you also know of any articles, whitepapers, or MSDN links that explain how LINQ works under the hood? I haven't found any on MSDN yet

Comment: @danderson - jon skeet has a 42 part blog series that will help: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Comment: Given the performance insignificance alluded to by @Reed, I tend to prefer consolidating all restricting conditions into `.Where` rather than passing them into things like `.Any`, `.First` or `.Single` for the purposes of clarity. +1 for that.

Comment: @Shibumi Really? I have the opposite preference. I always use `myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(predicate)` instead of `myEnumerable.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()` because I think the former is not only shorter but also more clear.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I can't say that what I wrote back in 2011 is representative of my current coding philosophy, nor can I even speak to why I thought that way, back then. Thanks for the comment, though!