# LINQ Any vs Exists Performance

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq .Any VS .Exists - Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference)

Is there a performance difference between using any vs exists in a LINQ query?  Specifically LINQ to Entities.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference

Comment: So, according to that post, EXISTS is not a linq method.  Therefore, am I to understand that ANY would be the only appropriate method to use to query the database to check if a record exists?

Comment: Well in LINQ to Entities, Exists() is not often not even available (on ObjectSet<>, IQueryable<>, etc.) Your only choice is Any(). Exists() will only be available if you first use ToList() in your LINQ queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Exists` requires an instance of `List<T>` while `Any` is invoked on `IEnumerable<T>`. This means you have the potential for increased memory efficiency as `IEnumerable<T>` can be evaluated lazily.