# Resolving bool from linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a property `OnHomePage` which is a bool.

I am trying to set this value based on whether a result is returned from a linq query or not. Obviously I could write an external method to determine whether the result of my query is null or whether it holds a value but I am hoping there is a better way for it to be done in one line.

Here is my current line of code as it stands:

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.Select(p => p.ImageId == im.Id 
                                      && p.Page.PageName == "/Home")
```

Comment: everybody answered without thinking  , DOES your bool should return true if at least 1 is true , or ALL of them ....?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I don't think that's fair to say. Speaking just for myself, I did pay attention to *"whether a result is returned from a linq query or not."* That's `Any`.

Comment: @jon my bad. Didnt see  ( unless fast-edited...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Any Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) to determine if a query gives any result or not:

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.Any(p => p.ImageId == im.Id 
                                   && p.Page.PageName == "/Home");
```

Comment: "Any" is especially good for this since it's short circuited and will stop iterating through the items when it finds a match.

Comment: @bryanbcook: So does `.Where(..).Any()`. `.Any(..)` may result in a more efficient translation to SQL though, depending on the LINQ provider.

Comment: @bryanbcook This is likely an IQueryable, not an Enumerable, so that depends entirely on the query provider.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply wrap up the query with [`.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx):

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.Where(p => p.ImageId == im.Id 
                                  && p.Page.PageName == "/Home")
                          .Any();
```

Or, just use the other overload of `Any` directly in the first place:

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.Any(p => p.ImageId == im.Id 
                                  && p.Page.PageName == "/Home");
```

Comment: need to change the `Select` to a `Where` in the first query.  The second query is fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.Where(p => p.ImageId == 
  im.Id && p.Page.PageName == "/Home").Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said other users you can use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx):

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.Any(p => p.ImageId == im.Id 
                                      && p.Page.PageName == "/Home");
```

Or another solution could be use [`Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx):

```
OnHomePage = im.PageImages.ToList().Exists(p => p.ImageId == im.Id 
                                          && p.Page.PageName == "/Home");
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference) is an interesting answer explain the differences.

**PS:**

> In behaviour, these are identical.