# LINQ method like List.Exists(predicate)?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for LINQ method like `List.Exists(predicate)`.

```
bool exists = mylist.Exists(p => p.Name == "Kamila");

bool exists = collection.??????(p => p.Name == "Kamila");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
//Will return true (and stop future iteration the moment the predicate is met)
//Otherwise false
bool exists = collection.Any(p => p.Name == "Kamila");
```

Comment: For linking to documentation, +1. I admire that.

Comment: @MikeEason - I always try to attack the SO documentation - many people work very hard - why not give credit :)

Comment: Another approach: `collection.Select(p => p.Name).Contains("Kamila")`

Comment: Another approach2(less readable): `!collection.All(p => p.Name != "Kamila")`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool exists = collection.Any(p => p.Name == "Kamila");
```

It is an [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) for any [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) defined on `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Check this post for more details: [Linq .Any VS .Exists - Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference)

Comment: #Gilad Green was 6 seconds faster :), but +1 for good answer.

Comment: @marbel82 Yes. I like this behavior.  :)