# CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from "Project.Vector2" to "System.Predicate<Project.Vector2>"

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if a position exists in a list containing positions.

```
    private bool PositionExists(List<Vector2> positions, Vector2 position)
    {
        return positions.Exists(position);
    }
```

This throws me the error

> CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from "Project.Vector2" to
>   "System.Predicate Project.Vector2"

Can I fix this or do I have to use Linq

```
return positions.Any(currentPos => currentPos == position);
```

Comment: You might want to put a lambda in your Exists, like `p => p == position`, but you'll end up with the same as Any, so you might as well just use that. Or write a predicate function...

Comment: So using `Any` but be better anyway?

Comment: I will refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference#879533
Essentially they are the same - at least if you use the lambda notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean...

```
return positions.Contains(position);
```