# count-down timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer

My main problem is that I don't know how to search what I'm looking for in google,because I get different results(probably its not count-down timer).

I want to calculate how much time a function takes to be executed.The instructions take a long time in seconds to be executed(seconds,not miliseconds).

How to do it in C#/NET,example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the StopWatch.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance) for more detail.

[Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find bottlenecks in you application you can check out the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&DisplayLang=en) as a starting point.