# Why does System.IO.Path.Combine have 4 overloads?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET 4, [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) has the following overloads for the `Combine` method:

```
public static string Combine(params string[] paths)
public static string Combine(string path1, string path2)
public static string Combine(string path1, string path2, string path3)
public static string Combine(string path1, string path2, string path3, string path4)
```

The first one was added in .NET 4 to support any number of path arguments. The second one was already there in earlier versions so I suppose it is kept for backwards compatibility.

But I'm curious what the use of the other overloads is. Aren't these use cases already covered by the first method signature with `params`?

**edit:** I now believe that the answer is "because not all languages have `params` support (and passing an array without params support is inconvenient)". However, the stackoverflow hive mind seems to disagree strongly. Therefore, as a compromise, I am not accepting any answer.

Comment: My guess is backward compatibility.

Comment: @Shurdoof only the second one was available before. The other three are all new to .NET 4, so there's no backwards-ness between the first, third, and fourth.

Comment: @Shurdoof - at .NET 3.5 there was only the 2nd method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Yeah, just remembered that. checked with reflector and they don't call the params overload, so it's probably for perfomance reasons.

Comment: @k3b You have a number of issue with your performance test which make it incorrect\inconclusive e.g. using DateTime.Now, not testing 2 and 3 parameter version, and not taking GC into consideration. I have updated my answer with more expanded tests on these issues.

Comment: @Wim There is some confusion here. Yes "params" is a C# keyword, but it is underpinned by a .Net concept: ParamArrayAttribute which is language agnostic. When you author a method using "params" it will use ParamArrayAttribute under the hood, and this is interpreted by the compiler. All .Net languages can consume these methods. In short "params" in an authoring issue related to C#, not a consuming issue related to all languages. I can consume a method written in C# with a "params" argument, from VB or F#. The compiler needs to support it, not the consumer.

Comment: @chibacity: I was already aware of the attribute and how it is used by compilers (C# params, VB.NET ParamArray, etcetera). However, I believe compilers are free to ignore it if they don't have support for such a feature. It is for these languages that a friendlier non-array version of the method is useful.

Comment: @Wim Yes, that's the point I'm making. If the compiler does support it, then any other language can then consume the produced library. Obviously the framework has been compiled with a compiler that supports "Path.Combine(params)" otherwise it would not be there. All languages can use the 'params' version of the Path.Combine method.

Comment: @chibacity: programmers in all languages can consume it by passing an object array, yes. But the programmers in languages without params support would have to type `Path.Combine(new string[] { "foo", "bar", "baz"});` or something worse if they don't have an array initialization syntax. To make things easier for them, a non-array overload has been added so that they can type the more convenient `Path.Combine("foo","bar","baz");`

Comment: @Wim Sure. There is no significant language that I know of that does not support integration with ParamArray. That includes C#, VB.Net, F# and managed C++.

Comment: Maybe they were following performance guidelines and simply screwed it up in some unforeseen way with a later - bug fix, enhancement or a refactor???

Answer (score 28):

I would suspect for performance as you have to create an intermediary array with params, plus the overhead of traversing the array, etc. There are probably some internal, etc, cases where there is a good case for using the fixed numbered parameter versions.

**Update**

I have now carried out performance tests to check my assumptions. This is something I should have done in the first place - I broke my own performance mantra:

> Don't think - measure.

My assumptions are not entirely correct, but not entirely wrong. The 4 fixed parameter version is marginally slower than the 4 params version, but the 3 and 2 fixed variations perform significantly better.

There are a number of issues with the performance test harness for the current accepted answer which states that performance goes entirely in favour of the params version - this is incorrect:

- It uses DateTime.Now for timing - always use a Stopwatch for micro benchmarking as DatTime.Now is only accurate to between ~10ms->15ms. [There are endless articles on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance).
- The test only covers the case of the 4 parameter version - what about the 3 and 2 parameter versions?
- Garbage generation and collection are not taken into consideration. One method might be faster in a straight line between A->B, but it might also generate a lot of garbage which will have to be cleaned up at some stage. This is a deferred performance penalty, but it is still a performance impact so should be taken into consideration.
- Ensure arguments have realistic values - is combining single character paths realistic?

I have the following performance results which I have included 2, 3 and 4 argument variations where it can be seen that performance is significantly better for 2 and 3 variations, and marginally worse for the 4 variation. The fixed number argument versions are faster on the whole though, with 3 being the most significant in terms of this question (the 2 argument variation existed since .Net 1.1).

```
***2 Args***
params2:3018.44ms
params2:3007.61ms
params2:2988.52ms
params2:2992.33ms
params2:2995.89ms
args2  :1724.83ms
args2  :1723.97ms
args2  :1727.76ms
args2  :1720.42ms
args2  :1718.24ms
***3 Args***
params3:4168.37ms
params3:4169.61ms
params3:4165.63ms
params3:4161.51ms
params3:4153.61ms
args3  :3476.96ms
args3  :3483.40ms
args3  :3482.49ms
args3  :3595.15ms
args3  :3561.11ms
***4 Args***
params4:4992.71ms
params4:4985.51ms
params4:4995.63ms
params4:5002.47ms
params4:4993.99ms
args4  :4993.02ms
args4  :4992.93ms
args4  :4991.07ms
args4  :4993.04ms
args4  :4995.14ms
```

Test:

```
public void MeasurePathPerformance()
{
    const int TestIterations = 5;
    const string Root = "C:\\xxxxxxxxxx";
    string seg = new string('x', 10);
    string path = null;

    Action<string, Func<double>> test = (name, action) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TestIterations; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1:F2}ms", name, action());
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine("***2 Args***");
    Action p2 = () => path = Path.Combine(new[] { Root, seg });
    test("params2", () => TimeTest(p2));
    Action a2 = () => path = Path.Combine(Root, seg);
    test("args2  ", () => TimeTest(a2));

    Console.WriteLine("***3 Args***");
    Action p3 = () => path = Path.Combine(new[] { Root, seg, seg });
    test("params3", () => TimeTest(p3));
    Action a3 = () => path = Path.Combine(Root, seg, seg);
    test("args3  ", () => TimeTest(a3));

    Console.WriteLine("***4 Args***");
    Action p4 = () => path = Path.Combine(new[] { Root, seg, seg, seg });
    test("params4", () => TimeTest(p4));
    Action a4 = () => path = Path.Combine(Root, seg, seg, seg);
    test("args4  ", () => TimeTest(a4));

    Console.WriteLine(path);
}

[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2001:AvoidCallingProblematicMethods", MessageId = "System.GC.Collect")]
private static double TimeTest(Action action)
{
    const int Iterations = 10 * 1000 * 1000;

    Action gc = () =>
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    };

    Action empty = () => { };

    Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int j = 0; j < Iterations; j++)
    {
        empty();
    }

    double loopElapsed = stopwatch1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    gc();

    action(); //JIT
    action(); //Optimize

    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int j = 0; j < Iterations; j++)
    {
        action();
    }

    gc();

    double testElapsed = stopwatch2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    return (testElapsed - loopElapsed);
}
```

Comment: after some reflectorizing (real word), I can confirm that the code for the two paths is much more efficient than the params version.

Comment: This is the the same reason that `String.Format` has multiple overloads that avoid the `params` argument.

Comment: Intuitively this would seem correct. But measurements show that the array version is actually faster. Can we all stop up-voting the wrong answer please?

Comment: @Wim Please see my updated answer. The answer you have accepted has a number of shortcomings in its performance test which mean its results are incorrect\inconclusive.

Comment: @chibacity: as your own performance tests show, performance is definitely not the reason why the 4 argument overload was added. My question was "why do all these overloads exist", not "which is the fastest". The only remaining plausible explanation is support for languages without `params` support, as stated in the accepted answer. This is the simplest explanation that explains the existence of all overloads. There is nothing "incorrect/inconclusive" about that.

Comment: @Wim The question is also not just about the 4 overload, it is about the 3 overload too. The accepted answer makes a black and white statement about performance which is untrue - there can be no argument about that. I refer to the performance part of the argument when I say "incorrect\inconclusive". I am not being ambiguous there. A problem with this question is that only a framework developer\designer can truly answer it, and it is likely to be for a number of reasons rather than just one.

Comment: @Wim My results could be used to support why a 3 parameter version exists. Each overload could have its own different reasons for being there. That's certainly plausible.

Comment: @chibacity: yes, but I applied Occam's razor and selected the simplest answer which explains everything. Anyway, I am tiring of the controversy surrounding this question and am no longer accepting any answer as a compromise. Enjoy your rep-boost ;-)

Comment: @Wim Sorry for being a bore, but the internet never forgets, etc. Even the answer about "params" is incorrect. Yes you author using "params" in C#, but it is actually represented by ParamArrayAttribute under the hood which is a .Net mechanism, and so not C# specific. The ParamArrayAttribute is interpreted by the language compiler. I can use it in C#, then consume the method from VB, F#, etc.

Comment: I verified that 2 parameter is about 50% faster and 3 parameter version is about 30% faster - that was my mistake. Sorry for that.

My test result was about the same as @chibacity-s code. I used my old testcode having Datetime.Now instead of stopwatch, unrealistic Path-values 
and did not take the Garbage-collector into account.

What i do not understand is why arguments should have realistic values if we are only comparing the performance 
difference overhead of array versus parameter and not the calculation itself.

Comment: @k3b When using a param array this really introduces a different problem - a variable number of arguments to deal with. This can quite likely lead to the fact that a fixed optimal way of dealing with a fixed number of parameters cannot be used as we don't know how many parameters there will be. Therefore fixed vs variable parameter methods could be algorithmically different, and input parameters may affect this. Therefore it's best to use "realistic" inputs. It's best to use realistic inputs for many reasons though, as we won't to ensure we have good performance for realistic sceanarios.

Answer (score 2):

What about syntactic shugar for languages that do not support something similar to the c#-"params" keyword

Update

Removed Performance issue since i measured only the 4 parameter version but not the 3 and 2 parameter version that are realy faster

<strike>The performance is not the reason. (See my benchmark below)</strike>

### Benchmark

I measured the performance. To my surprise the array version was slightly better.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MeasurePathPerfomance()
    {
        // repeat several times to avoid jit-issues
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

                string result;
                for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
                {
                    result = System.IO.Path.Combine("a", "b", "c", "d"); // use 4 parameter version
                }
                TimeSpan spend = DateTime.Now - start;
                System.Console.WriteLine("4 param : {0}", spend.TotalMilliseconds);
            }
            {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

                string result;
                for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
                {
                    result = System.IO.Path.Combine(new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
                }
                TimeSpan spend = DateTime.Now - start;
                System.Console.WriteLine("array[4] param : {0}", spend.TotalMilliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
```

result

```
    4 param : 10.001
    array[4] param : 9.0009
    4 param : 12.0012
    array[4] param : 8.0008
    4 param : 12.0012
    array[4] param : 10.001
    4 param : 11.0011
    array[4] param : 9.0009
    4 param : 11.0011
    array[4] param : 11.0011
    4 param : 11.0011
    array[4] param : 9.0009
    4 param : 10.001
    array[4] param : 8.0008
    4 param : 10.001
    array[4] param : 9.0009
    4 param : 11.0011
    array[4] param : 9.0009
    4 param : 11.0011
    array[4] param : 9.0009
```

Comment: I have confirmed your result: the array version is faster!

Comment: Thanks Wim for inspiraton. I reedited my article by moving the central issue ("params" equivalent) from bottom to top of article.

Comment: @k3b There are a number of issues with your performance test which make it incorrect\inconclusive. Please see my updated answer below.

Comment: Don't use DateTime.Now for performance measurements. Use Stopwatch instead.

Comment: @Wim There is some confusion here. Yes "params" is a C# keyword, but it is underpinned by a .Net concept: [ParamArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx) which is language agnostic. When you author a method using "params" it will use ParamArrayAttribute under the hood. All .Net languages can consume methods which have an argument decorated with ParamArrayAttribute. In short "params" in an authoring issue related to C#, not a consuming issue related to all languages. I can consume a method written in C# with a "params" argument, from VB or F#.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason can also be to reduce pressure on the garbage collector. The params-array overload creates a new array each time the method is called. If the method is called often, a lot of temporary array objects are created, increasing pressure on the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

Backwards compatibility is the best reason I can think of.  The overloads are probably all calling the first method.

Comment: " The overloads are probably all calling the first method." This  would explain why the array version is slightly faster than the parameter version. (See my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Its just because of performance, the performance of the last 3 is greater then the first method.

If you want to know the implementation, just look at mscorlib with reflector, you'll see the performance will be better in the last 3 functions

Comment: Then how do you explain k3b's measurements which show that the array version is faster?

Comment: As you see with 2 and 3 parameters are far faster, the one with 4 params is almost the same so I think the team said it's just for the ease of the developers ... yet my answer is indeed not 100% correct ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that most of programmers use one, two, three or four values to combine and more than that you want to think its better to implement an array rather to use more values.

**Example**

```
Sum(a , b); //fine
Sum(a , b , c);//fine
Sum(a , b , c , d);//fine
Sum(a , b , c , d ,....); //now I think you think everyone think  even Microsoft also thinks, its better to implement array here

// something like this
Sum(params var[] n);
```

So you will found most of the method holds 1,2,3,4 arguments and then params

Comment: Completely agree with you, I was going to say the same. Maybe the example would be better with a method.