# Is Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks threadsafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, stopwatch

If I have a shared `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instance, can multiple threads call `shared.ElapsedTicks` in a safe manner and get accurate results?

Is there any difference in terms of thread-safety/accuracy between using a shared instance of Stopwatch in this way, and using the static `GetTimeStamp()` method?

I'm measuring intervals of around 180ms, and finding that using the shared instance is giving me a larger spread of results, including a significant number that are shorter than I would expect.

The machine has multiple CPUs (2 * Intel X5550 for what it's worth)

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not asking whether I should share stopwatch instance members across multiple threads - that's clear from the link Magnus provided. I'm trying to understand/explain the unexpected behaviour of existing code, and wondered if a shared Stopwatch instance could be the problem.

Comment: Related possible implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799650/simple-lockless-stopwatch

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: +1, your answer is right.. add to it that `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();` is thread safe because it is static.

Comment: There used to be thread-safety information in MSDN documentation. But has apparently been removed.
Also code review and empirical testing seems to suggest that ElapsedXXX properties are thread safe as suggested by more recent answers.

Comment: @JalalSaid while that method should be threadsafe, would it give accurate results if you first call it on one thread and then a diffrent one and then subtract them to get the elapsed time?

Answer (score 10):

[Looking at the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs), *it is* thread-safe, but you must not use: `Stop()`, `Reset()` and `Restart()`.

So, if you start a shared instance, does not modify it and call only `ElapsedXXX` properties, you should be fine.

Comment: @apdevelop No, `ElapsedXXX` are not atomic, that's why you must not use `Stop(), Reset(), Restart()` from other thread. Just look at the source code.

Comment: I meant creating `Stopwatch` and calling its `Start`/`Stop` methods in one thread and then calling `ElapsedXXX` methods from another thread(s). _Atomic_ reading related to dealing with `Int64` fields from different threads, when we should use methods from `Interlocked` class. In case of reading `ElapsedMilliseconds` property it's not possible.

Comment: Empirical test on 64-bit machine with .NET 4.8 seems to confirm thread-safety of ElapsedXXX properties.

Comment: While this property is theadsafe as long as you do not call the `Start()`, `Reset()`, or `Stop()` methods, it is important to note that if you are using the ticks for arithmetic and then passing the value into a `TimeSpan` constructor, for example, one `stopWatch.ElapsedTicks` Tick is not equivalent to `TimeSpan` Ticks as described here: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/01/12/c.net-little-pitfalls-stopwatch-ticks-are-not-timespan-ticks.aspx. To get equivalent ticks you would want to use `stopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks`.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the source code, it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Are you able to infer what inaccuracies might occur? I ask because although I'm seeing unexpected results, they are not "impossible" ones - I'm not getting any negative measurements, or results that are orders of magnitude out. Even after millions of measurements.

Comment: On 32-bit machines, it's vulnerable to tearing if called while calling `Start()` or `Stop()`.  (it might read the `long elapsed` field while it's being written to).  On x64, it looks safe.

Comment: Does the `ElapsedTicks` method modify the underlying instance in any fashion that would cause multiple threads using that method to interfere with each other, if no such calls are simultaneous with other methods like `Start`, `Stop`, etc.?  I wouldn't think `ElapsedTicks` would need to modify any instance members at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ThreadLocal<T>
```

like this:

```
    ThreadLocal<Random> _localRandom = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
    ThreadLocal<Stopwatch> _localStopwatch = new ThreadLocal<Stopwatch>(() => new Stopwatch());

    public void SomeTest()
    {
        Action someAction = () =>
            {
                _localStopwatch.Value.Reset();
                _localStopwatch.Value.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(_localRandom.Value.Next(100, 500));
                _localStopwatch.Value.Stop();
                Debug.Print(_localStopwatch.Value.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            };

        var actions = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => someAction).ToArray();
        Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount}, actions);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is not about Stopwatch thread-safety. It is about how to provide separate Stopwatch instance to each thread.

Comment: This seems awfully convoluted, why use `ThreadLocal<Stopwatch>` when you can just declare a local variable inside the thread?

Comment: @Liam, yes, you can use the ThreadStatic attribute, but keep in mind that the default initializer will only call once for all threads, not one for each thread. So, I prefer to use ThreadLocal everywhere