# Thread Safe Method with a Stop Watch

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to determine if my code I'm using is Thread Safe or not.  I'm basically trying to call a method several times from different threads, and capture the time it takes for certain calls within the method to complete.

Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadTest
{
class Program
{
    static BlockingCollection<TimeSpan> Timer1 = new BlockingCollection<TimeSpan>(new ConcurrentBag<TimeSpan>());

    static TimeSpan CaptureTime(Action action)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }

    static void ThreadFunction()
    {
        TimeSpan timer1 = new TimeSpan();
        timer1 = CaptureTime(() =>
            {
                //Do Some Work
            });
        Timer1.Add(timer1);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            var task = new Task(ThreadFunction);
            task.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And what I'm trying to determine is whether or not the TimeSpan values returned by the CaptureTime method can be trusted.

Thank you to anyone who can enlighten me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664538/is-stopwatch-elapsedticks-threadsafe)

Answer (score 3):

Use of `Stopwatch` here is not the problem.  See this [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18643405/634824).  Since you are in a single thread when you use the Stopwatch, it will work fine.

But I'm not sure this approach is really going to be very useful.  Are you trying to create your own profiler? Why not just use existing profiling tools?

When you spin up 50 instances of the same operation, they're bound to fight for the same CPU resources.  Also, a new `Task` might or might not spin up a new thread.  Even then, the amount of switching involved would make the results less-than-meaningful.  Unless you are specifically trying to observe parallel behavior, I would avoid this approach.

The better way would be to run the action 50 times *sequentially*, time the whole thing, then divide by 50.  (Assuming this is a short-running task.)

<s>The using of `BlockingCollection<TimeSpan>(new ConcurrentBag<TimeSpan>())` is also very weird.  Since you are just adding to the list, and it is static and pre-created, then you can just use `List<TimeSpan>`.  See the notes on Thread Saftey in the `List<T>` documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).</s>

Ignore that.  I misunderstood the context of the docs.  Your code is just fine, and is indeed thread-safe.  Thanks to Jim and Alexi for clearing that up.

Comment: Also, questions of this nature are better posed at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: +1. On suggestions for better Stopwatch practices. Disagree on `List<T>` suggestion - list is not thread safe for adding from multiple threads, so it can't be used in this context. Also I'd disagree on if this question is better for codereview. To me it clearly about "if particular coding pattern is thread safe" without much concern how the rest of code written - SO feels appropriate.

Comment: If he used `List<T>` he would have to lock in order to add to it.

Comment: @JimMischel - Are you sure about the thread safety? MSDN says static instances are thread safe. If the list was being read or enumerated during this activity, I would I agree with you, but it's not.

Comment: No, it says "Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." So if there are public static *members* of `List<T>`, those are thread-safe. But any instance members (like `Add`, `Remove`, etc.) are not. It has nothing to do with whether the instance of `List<T>` is declared static. His code can have multiple threads calling `Add` at the same time. That will be a problem.

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for clearing that up.  That makes sense.  I'll edit my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They can be 'trusted' alright but that does not mean they will be very accurate.

It depends on lots of factors but basically you would want to measure a large number of calls to `action()` (on the same thread) and average them. Especially when a single call takes a relatively short time ( <= 1 ms)

You will still have to deal with external factors, Windows is not a Real Time OS.