# Is it safe to use Stopwatch in a method called by multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, stopwatch

I have a method that performs some work. I use a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch in that method to measure the time taken to execute the task performed by that method. This method is called several times by multiple threads as follows:

```
ArrayList workerThreads = new ArrayList();  

     for (int i = 0; i < numThread; i++)
        {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
            workerThread.IsBackground = true;
            workerThreads.Add(workerThread);
        }

for (int i = 0; i < numThread; i++)
            {                   
                ((Thread)workerThreads[i]).Start();
            }

public void DoWork()
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    // Do something
    sw.Stop();
    Log.Info(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

}
```

Is it thread safe to use Stopwatch the way I am? Will the results be accurate or do I need to explicitly lock it so the threads won't step over each other's values of Elapsed time there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664538/is-stopwatch-elapsedticks-threadsafe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no thread safety concerns involved, because you are not sharing instance of `Stopwatch` across threads.

In theory `Stopwatch.StartNew` could be thread unsafe, [but it is not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. I was curious because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573756/stopwatch-misbehaving-because-of-multiple-threads) scenario I am facing: