# Send multiple requests at once to my WebAPI using Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await

I'm trying to send multiple same requests at (almost) once to my WebAPI to do some performance testing.
For this, I am calling `PerformRequest` multiple times and wait for them using `await Task.WhenAll`.

I want to calculate the time that each request takes to complete plus the start time of each one of them. In my code,however, I don't know what happens if the result of R3 (request number 3) comes before R1? Would the duration be wrong?

From what I see in the results, I think the results are mixing with each other. For example, the R4's result sets as R1's result. So any help would be appreciated.

`GlobalStopWatcher` is a static class that I'm using to find the start time of each request.

Basically I want to make sure that `elapsedMilliseconds` and `Duration` of each request is associated with the request itself. 
So that if the result of request 10th comes before the result of 1st request, then duration would be `duration = elapsedTime(10th)-(startTime(1st))`. Isn't that the case?

I wanted to add a `lock` but it seems impossible to add it where there's `await` keyword.

```
 public async Task<RequestResult> PerformRequest(RequestPayload requestPayload)
    {
        var url = "myUrl.com";

        var client = new RestClient(url) { Timeout = -1 };

        var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.POST };

        request.AddHeaders(requestPayload.Headers);
        foreach (var cookie in requestPayload.Cookies)
        {
            request.AddCookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value);
        }
        request.AddJsonBody(requestPayload.BodyRequest);

        var st = new Stopwatch();
        st.Start();
        var elapsedMilliseconds = GlobalStopWatcher.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        var result = await client.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        st.Stop();
        var duration = st.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        return new RequestResult() 
        { 
           Millisecond = elapsedMilliseconds,
           Content = result.Content,
           Duration = duration
        };
     }



public async Task RunAllTasks(int numberOfRequests)
{
    GlobalStopWatcher.Stopwatch.Start();

    var arrTasks = new Task<RequestResult>[numberOfRequests];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
    {
         arrTasks[i] = _requestService.PerformRequest(requestPayload, false);
    }

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(arrTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    RequestsFinished?.Invoke(this, results.ToList());
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the results are mixing?

Comment: @GabrielLuci let's say we are firing 100 requests in the `ForLoop`. The `elapsedMilliseconds` for the first request would be, for example, 1ms and 100ms for the last request.However, the result of 100th requests comes before the result of 1st one. Wouldn't that return the result content of the 100th request (which came first) and the `elapsedMilliseconds` of the first request (which came last)?

Comment: You have a local `Stopwatch` separate for each request, and a global `Stopwatch` for all requests. You call "Duration" the measurement obtained by the local `Stopwatch`, and "Millisecond" the measurement obtained by the global `Stopwatch`. Which of two measurements are you concerned than may be wrong, the local, the global, or both?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Both of them. I want to know after how many milliseconds that request fired (`elapsedMilliseconds`) and how long that request took to accomplished(`duration`)

Comment: Then your question is probably too broad. Here we are allowed to ask only one question per post. Regarding the global `Stopwatch`, you may find this question interesting: [Is Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664538/is-stopwatch-elapsedticks-threadsafe)

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - Can you please provide a [mcve]? I'd like to copy, paste, and (at least) compile your code. I prefer to be able to actually run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where I think you're going wrong with this is trying to use a static `GlobalStopWatcher` and then pushing this code into your function that you're testing.

You should keep everything separate and use a new instance of `Stopwatch` for each `RunAllTasks` call.

Let's make it so.

Start with these:

```
public async Task<RequestResult<R>> ExecuteAsync<R>(Stopwatch global, Func<Task<R>> process)
{
    var s = global.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var c = await process();
    var d = global.ElapsedMilliseconds - s;
    return new RequestResult<R>()
    {
        Content = c,
        Millisecond = s,
        Duration = d
    };
}

public class RequestResult<R>
{
    public R Content;
    public long Millisecond;
    public long Duration;
}
```

Now you're in a position to test anything that fits the signature of `Func<Task<R>>`.

Let's try this:

```
public async Task<int> DummyAsync(int x)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x % 3));
    return x;
}
```

We can set up a test like this:

```
public async Task<RequestResult<int>[]> RunAllTasks(int numberOfRequests)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var tasks = 
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfRequests)
        select ExecuteAsync<int>(sw, () => DummyAsync(i));
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Note that the line `var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();` captures a new `Stopwatch` for each `RunAllTasks` call. Nothing is actually "global" anymore.

If I execute that with `RunAllTasks(7)` then I get this result:

[image: Dummy Test]

It runs and it counts correctly.

Now you can just refactor your `PerformRequest` method to just do what it needs to:

```
public async Task<string> PerformRequest(RequestPayload requestPayload)
{
    var url = "myUrl.com";
    var client = new RestClient(url) { Timeout = -1 };
    var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.POST };
    request.AddHeaders(requestPayload.Headers);
    foreach (var cookie in requestPayload.Cookies)
    {
        request.AddCookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value);
    }
    request.AddJsonBody(requestPayload.BodyRequest);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    return response.Content;
}
```

Running the tests is easy:

```
public async Task<RequestResult<string>[]> RunAllTasks(int numberOfRequests)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var tasks = 
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfRequests)
        select ExecuteAsync<string>(sw, () => _requestService.PerformRequest(requestPayload));
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

If there's any doubt about the thread-safety of `Stopwatch` then you could do this:

```
public async Task<RequestResult<R>> ExecuteAsync<R>(Func<long> getMilliseconds, Func<Task<R>> process)
{
    var s = getMilliseconds();
    var c = await process();
    var d = getMilliseconds() - s;
    return new RequestResult<R>()
    {
        Content = c,
        Millisecond = s,
        Duration = d
    };
}

public async Task<RequestResult<int>[]> RunAllTasks(int numberOfRequests)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var tasks = 
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfRequests)
        select ExecuteAsync<int>(() => { lock (sw) { return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; } }, () => DummyAsync(i));
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Accessing the instance property `ElapsedMilliseconds` of a non-thread-safe class from multiple threads without synchronization seems risky though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Not according to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664538/is-stopwatch-elapsedticks-threadsafe. There are a number of answers there saying as long as you don't start, stop, or restart the `Stopwatch` then it is safe. I suppose I could wrap it in a `Func<long>` and put a lock around it though.

Comment: @Enigmativity very nice answer. One question though. Is the `lock` there because of `Task.WhenAll` running all the tasks in parallel?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - The `lock` is there because we want to ensure that access to the `Stopwatch` is thread-safe. Nonetheless, `Task.WhenAll` doesn't create or use any threads. It's just in case this code is changed so that `ExecAsync` (or something deeper) uses other threads.