# Which is Faster List<string>.foreach or listString.GetEnumerator()

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have written the following code to print the item values inside the list. Now I want to measure which one is faster as going forward I will have huge list to deal with. And please specify why you think that's better (if any evidences)

So how do I calculate the processing time? Is manually creating a bulky List is the only option?

```
  public void printMedod(string strPrintListVal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strPrintListVal);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p1 = new Program();

            List<string> listString = new List<string> { "Rox","Stephens","Manahat","Lexus",":)"};
            listString.ForEach(p1.printMedod);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I can also do the same thing using GetEnumerator:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> listString = new List<string> { "Rox","Stephens","Manahat","Lexus",":)"};
            var enumerator = listString.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var pair = enumerator.Current;
                Console.WriteLine(pair);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: don't use the `ForEach` extension, whats wrong with a `foreach` loop? If you want to know which is faster, time them.

Comment: Aside: `foreach obj in list` is actually inlined to a `while` using `GetEnumerator()` so those two should be equivalent.

Comment: *how do I calculate the processing time*, you can use a `Stopwatch`

Comment: @V4Vendetta, Seriously , that is what we are left with !!!!

Comment: @Simsons :) well i meant [This Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) but that was indeed funny

Comment: @V4Vendetta, Indeed great . Thnx

Comment: The biggest performance between these two samples would likely be the use of `Program.printMedod`

Comment: Old but relavent http://diditwith.net/PermaLink,guid,506c0888-8c5f-40e5-9d39-a09e2ebf3a55.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I'd `ForEach` my way through the list, but I've been told a for loop is faster than anything else:

```
for(int i = 0;i < stringList.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stringList[i]);
}
```

Comment: I believe, if the underying type has a fast indexer then yes. Especially useful for arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), it displays an execution time

Answer (score 1):

Neither is the best option here, just do

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stringList = new List<string> 
        { "Rox", "Stephens", "Manahat", "Lexus", ":)" };

    foreach(var s in stringList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

use a [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stopwatch.aspx) more info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28637/659190)

```
using System.Diagnotics;

var stopWatch = new StopWatch();

stopWatch.Start();

// Do somthing
// If somthing is really fast do lots of somthing

stopWatch.Stop();

// The duration is a TimeSpan in stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get to know? Is there way we can measure the processing time

Comment: As someone said in the comments above, that is inlined to a `while`-loop with `GetEnumerator()` so it's not faster then writing code using `GetEnumerator()` yourself.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, agreed, but its not slower either but more common and therefore, I suggest, more readable.