# How to track time between two button clicks in C# in a Windows form application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a windows form application in c# in which input from user is taken .I want to calculate time spent by user in between two submissions.How can I do that?

Comment: Is buttons in same form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). Create object of the Stopwatch at class level and use that to calculate time.

Something like:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Start();

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            stopwatch.Stop();
            var milliSeocnds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var timeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: (and some extra logic if the buttons can be pressed in either order)

Comment: @Davy8, oh yes, My code is just displaying usage of stop watch

Answer (score 3):

You can use two global DateTime variable and in click twice button diff to variable;

```
   private DateTime btn1Click ;
   private DateTime btn2click;


        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn1Click = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn2click = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

and use this code for diff time:

```
 TimeSpan timespan = btn2click - btn1Click;
```

---

In same button :

```
  private DateTime btnClick1 ;
        private DateTime btnClick2;

  private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnClick1==null)
            {
                btnClick1 = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                btnClick2 = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance

Comment: I want to calculate duration between two clicks for same button in same form

Answer (score 0):

Using System.Threading you can use the stopwatch function. Just start the function on the first click and stop it on the second.

```
Using System.Threading

//main etc ignored

//declare

Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

//start
s.start();
//stop
s.stop()
//get the time
s.Elapsed;
```