# time diiference between two button clicks on different windows form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a windows form application in c# in which input from user is taken .I want to calculate time spent by user in between two submissions.How can I do that?
The buttons are on different windows forms.

Comment: set a time counter activated by one button and closed by another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track time between two button clicks in C# in a Windows form application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048857/how-to-track-time-between-two-button-clicks-in-c-sharp-in-a-windows-form-applica)

Comment: @Jane dow How do I stop the stopwatch on another form.The question which you are referring has both buttons on same form.

Comment: global variable like `timerInProgress = true/false`

Answer (score 2):

```
public TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
public Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

public void triggerTimer()
{
   if (StopWatch.IsRunning)
   { 
     stopWatch.Stop();
     ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
   }
   else stopWatch.Start();

}
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  triggerTimer();
  //your code
}
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   triggerTimer();
   //your code
}
```

Read more about  [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).