# When the benchmark started?

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    DateTime date;

    public static void Main()
    {
        date = Datetime.Now;
        sw.Start();
        // do some work
        sw.Stop();
        Log(String.Format("App started on {0}, run time is {1}.", date, sw.ToRedableString()));
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to get the `Stopwatch` start date/time? I'm looking for something like `sw.GetStartDateTime()`.

Comment: What is this `ToRedableString()` method? Never heard of such one.

Comment: Not really. `Stopwatch` knows nothing about the real time clock.

Comment: @UweKeim: Clearly a badly named extension method. ;p

Comment: @UweKeim: A made-up extension method, I didn't consider it's implemntation important regaring this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just subtract `sw.Elapsed` from `DateTime.Now` and you'll have your starting point.

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// do work
sw.Stop();
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(sw.Elapsed);
Log(String.Format("App started on {0}, run time is {1}.", startDate, sw.Elapsed));
```

Comment: There is probably no benefit over using this compared to the OP's version.

Comment: @leppie I think he's looking for a way to do that, which is provided in my answer. His `sw.GetStartDateTime()` is just a dummy, I think.

Answer (score -1):

A better way of doing this is to use DateTimes

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
// doWork()
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
Log(String.Format("App started at {0}, run time is {1}.", start, (end - start).toString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: What makes this 'better'?

Comment: DateTime is potentially lower precision than Stopwatch. Stopwatch uses a high precision timer if it's available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance

Comment: @leppie becuase this way you do not need to calculate the start time, you have it to the millisecond. If you need better resolution, you need better resolution. OP never stated he needed to track to the Femptosecond.

Comment: @AlexAnderson: `DateTime.Now` does not have millisecond accuracy, it does have millisecond resolution. And sometimes microseconds matters for micro-benchmarks.