# 'Set Timing On' statement's Output in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlplus

Set timing on statement tells us the amount of time consumed to process a query after each query in SQL-Plus. I need to know if there is a way to get the same time consumed output in C#? (A select command to get time consumed for last executed query from data dictionary or something like that)

Comment: There is nothing like that built in. You can use a `StopWatch` to time whatever it is that you want to time, however.

Comment: As mentioned above there is no such thing for this natively, but I suggest you to take a look at  command pattern. Where you can create your commands and queries and decorate them with such audits as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to any `List` or `Collection` types to get execution time, however you could do something like this:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

TimedCommandsToExecute();

TimeSpan cost = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);
```

As pointed out below by @GlorinOakenfoot - the use of StopWatch is more accurate. Refer to this SO question/answer: [Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance/28648#28648)

Comment: Note that although this is *valid*, `StopWatch` is the preferred method as it may be more precise. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28648/4372746

Comment: You're correct, I was simply providing a pattern example. =)