# How to measure time in millisecond precision by thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I need to measure an event time precisely (suppose the time between two clicks). I used a timer and set the interval to "1" and a counter inside Tick event. The problem is since there are a lot of lines in my code the Tick event does not actually happen every 1ms (maybe every 8ms or more). Is there any way to use a thread and run a 1ms-timer independently in it?

Comment: I doubt you'll get that level of accuracy. With 8ms you should be glad.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28648/578411 but there is more to find when you search for `high precision timer [c#]`

Comment: Typically if you need to *measure* an interval you would be using a `Stopwatch` not a `Timer`.

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to measure? If all your doing is counting in milliseconds then you probably don't want to use an actual count at all. Just get a timestamp difference when you need to use the value

Comment: @musefan it is actually the human reaction time in milliseconds.

Comment: @Dcember: On first click, record timestamp. On second click, get timestamp and subtract the first from it. Then you have the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
        //start
        long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        //to do something
        //...

        //end
        long end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        long delta = end - start;
```

Comment: Measuring directly using StopWatch is far better.

Comment: I want you to see Stopwatch class source code
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,ceb0ba9cc88de82e

Answer (score 1):

```
var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// do something

stopWatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```