# How to display SQL result message in Winforms app?

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, message, npgsql

I want to show an execution message in my C# app. I am using npgsql, and I want to take the message from pgadmin as it is when the query is executed without customizing it. Are there any related methods?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get affected rows on ExecuteNonQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059158/get-affected-rows-on-executenonquery)

Comment: umm....... no, i want to get affected rows and total query time. (not just rows count)
Simply, I want to get the message (like the picture in the question post) that comes out when the query is executed.

Comment: then you'll also want to reference [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394060/how-do-i-time-the-execution-of-an-sql-query-in-c).

Comment: I thought there seem to be a function that returns the message (cf: Successfully run.) that comes out when the query is executed. If npgsql doesn't have that feature, i'll end up having to customize it like you said. 